# How to create encoder for Option type constructor, e.g. Option[Int]?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, frameless

Is it possible to use `Option[_]` member in a case class used with Dataset API? eg. `Option[Int]`

I tried to find an example but could not find any yet. This can probably be done with with a custom encoder (mapping?) but I could not find an example for that yet.

This might be achievable using Frameless library: https://github.com/adelbertc/frameless but there should be an easy way to get it done with base Spark libraries.

**Update**

I am using: `"org.apache.spark"   %% "spark-core"   % "1.6.1"`

And getting the following error when trying to use an Option[Int]:

> Unable to find encoder for type stored in a Dataset.  Primitive types
>   (Int, String, etc) and Product types (case classes) are supported by
>   importing sqlContext.implicits._  Support for serializing other types
>   will be added in future releases

**Solution update**

Since I was prototyping I was just declaring the case class inside the function before the conversion to the Dataset (in my case inside `object Main {`).

Option types worked just fine when I moved the case class outside of the Main function.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We only define implicits for a subset of the types we support [in SQLImplicits](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v1.6.1/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/SQLImplicits.scala#L40-L126).  We should probably consider adding `Option[T]` for common `T` as the internal infrastructure does understand `Option`. You can workaround this by either creating a `case class`, using a `Tuple` or [constructing the required  implicit yourself](https://databricks-prod-cloudfront.cloud.databricks.com/public/4027ec902e239c93eaaa8714f173bcfc/1023043053387187/1303696844214163/2840265927289860/latest.html) (though this is using and internal API so may break in future releases).

```
implicit def optionalInt: org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder[Option[Int]] = org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder()

val ds = Seq(Some(1), None).toDS()
```

Comment: I found the mistake I was doing, it seems that scala treats declaring a case class inside a function and outside of it differently. Declaring the case class outside of Main allowed the `as[_]` function to work correctly without any extra implicit. I tried using the implicit you mentioned but I could not get it working (for the case when the case class is defined inside a function, eg. Main). My datasource is a MS SQL Server DB.

Comment: For some reason Timestamp type encoding works but GregorianCalendar does not, both are not listed in the file mentioned in AlexeyRomanov's comment

Answer (score 2):

"Support for serializing other types will be added in future releases". Custom encoders aren't supported yet though obviously it's planned. You could try to implement the trait yourself, but there are certainly no official examples.

One option would be to use a `Seq[Int]` member and ensure it only has at most one value.

Comment: You could take this answer and my comment above and combine them -- a case class called `OptionalInt` wrapped around a `Seq[Int]`. Then you could implement `isDefined` and `isEmpty` and `get` and even `getOrElse` in the case class.

Comment: @DavidGriffin: Could you add an answer for that please? My Scala is a little bit rusty. I will try to implement it meanwhile.

Comment: @Alexey Romanov: It seems that `Seq[Int]` is treated as an unsuported type also so it won't work.

Comment: @RăzvanPanda Strange, it's listed in https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v1.6.1/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/SQLImplicits.scala#L72.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov I see, would you mind giving it a try? Maybe I did something wrong, but it did not work for me.