# How to store custom objects in Dataset?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset, apache-spark-encoders

According to [Introducing Spark Datasets](https://databricks.com/blog/2016/01/04/introducing-apache-spark-datasets.html):

> As we look forward to Spark 2.0, we plan some exciting improvements to Datasets, specifically:
>   ...
>   Custom encoders – while we currently autogenerate encoders for a wide variety of types, we’d like to open up an API for custom objects.

and attempts to store custom type in a `Dataset` lead to following error like:

> Unable to find encoder for type stored in a Dataset. Primitive types (Int, String, etc) and Product types (case classes) are supported by importing sqlContext.implicits._ Support for serializing other types will be added in future releases

or:

> Java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No Encoder found for ....

Are there any existing workarounds?

---

Note this question exists only as an entry point for a Community Wiki answer. Feel free to update / improve both question and answer.

Comment: looks like they added support in 3.2 https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-23862

Answer (score 264, accepted):

## Update

This answer is still valid and informative, although things are now better since 2.2/2.3, which adds built-in encoder support for `Set`, `Seq`, `Map`, `Date`, `Timestamp`, and `BigDecimal`. If you stick to making types with only case classes and the usual Scala types, you should be fine with just the implicit in `SQLImplicits`.

---

Unfortunately, virtually nothing has been added to help with this. Searching for `@since 2.0.0` in [`Encoders.scala`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.0.0/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Encoders.scala#L270-L316) or [`SQLImplicits.scala`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.0.0/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/SQLImplicits.scala#L77-L96) finds things mostly to do with primitive types (and some tweaking of case classes). So, first thing to say: **there currently is no real good support for custom class encoders**. With that out of the way, what follows is some tricks which do as good a job as we can ever hope to, given what we currently have at our disposal. As an upfront disclaimer: this won't work perfectly and I'll do my best to make all limitations clear and upfront.

#### What exactly is the problem

When you want to make a dataset, Spark "requires an encoder (to convert a JVM object of type T to and from the internal Spark SQL representation) that is generally created automatically through implicits from a `SparkSession`, or can be created explicitly by calling static methods on `Encoders`" (taken from the [docs on `createDataset`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession@createDataset[T](data:Seq[T])(implicitevidence$4:org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder[T]):org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[T])). An encoder will take the form `Encoder[T]` where `T` is the type you are encoding. The first suggestion is to add `import spark.implicits._` (which gives you [these](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.0.0/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/SQLImplicits.scala) implicit encoders) and the second suggestion is to explicitly pass in the implicit encoder using [this](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.0.0/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Encoders.scala) set of encoder related functions.

There is no encoder available for regular classes, so

```
import spark.implicits._
class MyObj(val i: Int)
// ...
val d = spark.createDataset(Seq(new MyObj(1),new MyObj(2),new MyObj(3)))
```

will give you the following implicit related compile time error:

> Unable to find encoder for type stored in a Dataset. Primitive types (Int, String, etc) and Product types (case classes) are supported by importing sqlContext.implicits._ Support for serializing other types will be added in future releases

However, if you wrap whatever type you just used to get the above error in some class that extends `Product`, the error confusingly gets delayed to runtime, so

```
import spark.implicits._
case class Wrap[T](unwrap: T)
class MyObj(val i: Int)
// ...
val d = spark.createDataset(Seq(Wrap(new MyObj(1)),Wrap(new MyObj(2)),Wrap(new MyObj(3))))
```

Compiles just fine, but fails at runtime with

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No Encoder found for MyObj

The reason for this is that the encoders Spark creates with the implicits are actually only made at runtime (via scala relfection). In this case, all Spark checks at compile time is that the outermost class extends `Product` (which all case classes do), and only realizes at runtime that it still doesn't know what to do with `MyObj` (the same problem occurs if I tried to make a `Dataset[(Int,MyObj)]` - Spark waits until runtime to barf on `MyObj`). These are central problems that are in dire need of being fixed:

- some classes that extend `Product` compile despite always crashing at runtime and
- there is no way of passing in custom encoders for nested types (I have no way of feeding Spark an encoder for just `MyObj` such that it then knows how to encode `Wrap[MyObj]` or `(Int,MyObj)`).

#### Just use `kryo`

The solution everyone suggests is to use the [`kryo`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.0.0/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Encoders.scala#L151) encoder.

```
import spark.implicits._
class MyObj(val i: Int)
implicit val myObjEncoder = org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders.kryo[MyObj]
// ...
val d = spark.createDataset(Seq(new MyObj(1),new MyObj(2),new MyObj(3)))
```

This gets pretty tedious fast though. Especially if your code is manipulating all sorts of datasets, joining, grouping etc. You end up racking up a bunch of extra implicits. So, why not just make an implicit that does this all automatically?

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag
implicit def kryoEncoder[A](implicit ct: ClassTag[A]) = 
  org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders.kryo[A](ct)
```

And now, it seems like I can do almost anything I want (the example below won't work in the `spark-shell` where `spark.implicits._` is automatically imported)

```
class MyObj(val i: Int)

val d1 = spark.createDataset(Seq(new MyObj(1),new MyObj(2),new MyObj(3)))
val d2 = d1.map(d => (d.i+1,d)).alias("d2") // mapping works fine and ..
val d3 = d1.map(d => (d.i,  d)).alias("d3") // .. deals with the new type
val d4 = d2.joinWith(d3, $"d2._1" === $"d3._1") // Boom!
```

Or almost. The problem is that using `kryo` leads to Spark just storing every row in the dataset as a flat binary object. For `map`, `filter`, `foreach` that is enough, but for operations like `join`, Spark really needs these to be separated into columns. Inspecting the schema for `d2` or `d3`, you see there is just one binary column:

```
d2.printSchema
// root
//  |-- value: binary (nullable = true)
```

#### Partial solution for tuples

So, using the magic of implicits in Scala (more in [6.26.3 Overloading Resolution](http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#overloading-resolution)), I can make myself a series of implicits that will do as good a job as possible, at least for tuples, and will work well with existing implicits:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Encoder,Encoders}
import scala.reflect.ClassTag
import spark.implicits._  // we can still take advantage of all the old implicits

implicit def single[A](implicit c: ClassTag[A]): Encoder[A] = Encoders.kryo[A](c)

implicit def tuple2[A1, A2](
  implicit e1: Encoder[A1],
           e2: Encoder[A2]
): Encoder[(A1,A2)] = Encoders.tuple[A1,A2](e1, e2)

implicit def tuple3[A1, A2, A3](
  implicit e1: Encoder[A1],
           e2: Encoder[A2],
           e3: Encoder[A3]
): Encoder[(A1,A2,A3)] = Encoders.tuple[A1,A2,A3](e1, e2, e3)

// ... you can keep making these
```

Then, armed with these implicits, I can make my example above work, albeit with some column renaming

```
class MyObj(val i: Int)

val d1 = spark.createDataset(Seq(new MyObj(1),new MyObj(2),new MyObj(3)))
val d2 = d1.map(d => (d.i+1,d)).toDF("_1","_2").as[(Int,MyObj)].alias("d2")
val d3 = d1.map(d => (d.i  ,d)).toDF("_1","_2").as[(Int,MyObj)].alias("d3")
val d4 = d2.joinWith(d3, $"d2._1" === $"d3._1")
```

I haven't yet figured out how to get the expected tuple names (`_1`, `_2`, ...) by default without renaming them - if someone else wants to play around with this, [this](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.0.0/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Encoders.scala#L205) is where the name `"value"` gets introduced and [this](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/encoders/ExpressionEncoder.scala#L108) is where the tuple names are usually added. However, the key point is that that I now have a nice structured schema:

```
d4.printSchema
// root
//  |-- _1: struct (nullable = false)
//  |    |-- _1: integer (nullable = true)
//  |    |-- _2: binary (nullable = true)
//  |-- _2: struct (nullable = false)
//  |    |-- _1: integer (nullable = true)
//  |    |-- _2: binary (nullable = true)
```

So, in summary, this workaround:

- allows us to get separate columns for tuples (so we can join on tuples again, yay!)
- we can again just rely on the implicits (so no need to be passing in `kryo` all over the place)
- is almost entirely backwards compatible with `import spark.implicits._` (with some renaming involved)
- does *not* let us join on the `kyro` serialized binary columns, let alone on fields those may have
- has the unpleasant side-effect of renaming some of the tuple columns to "value" (if necessary, this can be undone by converting `.toDF`, specifying new column names, and converting back to a dataset - and the schema names seem to be preserved through joins, where they are most needed).

#### Partial solution for classes in general

This one is less pleasant and has no good solution. However, now that we have the tuple solution above, I have a hunch the implicit conversion solution from another answer will be a bit less painful too since you can convert your more complex classes to tuples. Then, after creating the dataset, you'd probably rename the columns using the dataframe approach. If all goes well, this is *really* an improvement since I can now perform joins on the fields of my classes. If I had just used one flat binary `kryo` serializer that wouldn't have been possible.

Here is an example that does a bit of everything: I have a class `MyObj` which has fields of types `Int`, `java.util.UUID`, and `Set[String]`. The first takes care of itself. The second, although I could serialize using `kryo` would be more useful if stored as a `String` (since `UUID`s are usually something I'll want to join against). The third really just belongs in a binary column.

```
class MyObj(val i: Int, val u: java.util.UUID, val s: Set[String])

// alias for the type to convert to and from
type MyObjEncoded = (Int, String, Set[String])

// implicit conversions
implicit def toEncoded(o: MyObj): MyObjEncoded = (o.i, o.u.toString, o.s)
implicit def fromEncoded(e: MyObjEncoded): MyObj =
  new MyObj(e._1, java.util.UUID.fromString(e._2), e._3)
```

Now, I can create a dataset with a nice schema using this machinery:

```
val d = spark.createDataset(Seq[MyObjEncoded](
  new MyObj(1, java.util.UUID.randomUUID, Set("foo")),
  new MyObj(2, java.util.UUID.randomUUID, Set("bar"))
)).toDF("i","u","s").as[MyObjEncoded]
```

And the schema shows me I columns with the right names and with the first two both things I can join against.

```
d.printSchema
// root
//  |-- i: integer (nullable = false)
//  |-- u: string (nullable = true)
//  |-- s: binary (nullable = true)
```

Comment: Is it possible to create a custom class `ExpressionEncoder` using JSON serialization? In my case I cannot get away with tuples, and kryo gives me a binary column..

Comment: @AlexeyS I don't think so. But why would you want that? Why can you not get away with the last solution I propose? If you can put your data in JSON, you should be able to extract the fields and put them in a case class...

Comment: Unfortunately the bottomline of this answer is that there is not solution that works.

Comment: @baol Sort of. But remember how difficult what Spark is doing is. Scala's type system is simply not powerful enough to "derive" encoders that recursively go through fields. Frankly, I'm just surprised nobody made an annotation macro for this. Seems like the natural (but difficult) solution.

Comment: Doesn't your last solution turn things into dataframes in order to manipulate them? What if I want to work only in Spark 2.0 Datasets?

Comment: @combinatorist Yes, it turns them into dataframes. That said, `type
DataFrame = Dataset[Row]`, so this is still `Dataset` based. If your objection is about how I am playing fast and loose with types: you are right, I am, but Spark does that anyways. :)

Comment: @alec, it wasn't an objection, I was just trying to understand. I guess conceptually, the lesson learned is that I can't use this approach strictly within the dataset API, but "who cares" - people switch between RDD's, Datasets, and Dataframes freely in Spark anyway. Is that accurate? I guess I cared, because I want to make sure I have the compile-time type safety of the Datasets but the Dataframe API does not guarantee that, right? Maybe this is not much of an issue in actual practice (although it's the main reason I'm trying to use Scala over Python in production).

Comment: @combinatorist My understanding is that Datasets and Dataframes (but not RDDs, since they don't need encoders!) are equivalent from a performance perspective. Don't under-estimate the type-safety of Datasets! Just because Spark internally uses a ton of reflection, casts, etc. does not mean you shouldn't care about the type-safety of the interface that is exposed. But it does make me feel better about creating my own Dataset-based type-safe functions that use Dataframes under the hood.

Comment: Great answer! Is there any reference regarding the Encoders support for Set in Scala? I'm facing an issue when I'm creating a Set of a simple case class, whose definition is below:

    case class Session(start: Short, end: Short)

Comment: I have a solution that works as a charm. It consists in:

1. Define a sparkSql UDT over the custom class
2. register it
3. Enclose your class in a Product (Tuple1 for example)

Comment: Have you looked into using UDTRegistration?

Comment: Yeah it sucks that this use case is not supported by Spark in a sane way

Comment: @Alec Hi, does the line `val d2 = d1.map(d => (d.i+1, d)).toDF("_1","_2").as[(Int,MyObj)].alias("d2")` under **Just use kryo** section really work? It should have given error "**Unable to find encoder**" since it requires a new custom type, right? So it should already fail before the `joinWith` step.

Comment: Part of the answer seems incorrect "_I have no way of feeding Spark an encoder for just MyObj such that it then knows how to encode Wrap[MyObj] or (Int,MyObj)_" - See explanation **[in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36648128/how-to-store-custom-objects-in-dataset/64252485#64252485)** and **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64190037/how-to-store-nested-custom-objects-in-spark-dataset/64248200#64248200)**

Comment: I tried to run spark.sql("create table if not exists table1 (a Integer, b MyObj)") and it says org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException: DataType myobj is not supported. Can this be fixed so that I can create an empty table?

Answer (score 35):

1. Using generic encoders.

   There are two generic encoders available for now [`kryo`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/ae1db91d158d1ae62a0ab7ea74467679ca050101/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Encoders.scala#L149) and [`javaSerialization`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/ae1db91d158d1ae62a0ab7ea74467679ca050101/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Encoders.scala#L171) where the latter one is explicitly described as:

   > extremely inefficient and should only be used as the last resort.

   Assuming following class

   ```
   class Bar(i: Int) {
     override def toString = s"bar $i"
     def bar = i
   }
   ```

   you can use these encoders by adding implicit encoder:

   ```
   object BarEncoders {
     implicit def barEncoder: org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder[Bar] = 
     org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders.kryo[Bar]
   }
   ```

   which can be used together as follows:

   ```
   object Main {
     def main(args: Array[String]) {
       val sc = new SparkContext("local",  "test", new SparkConf())
       val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
       import sqlContext.implicits._
       import BarEncoders._

       val ds = Seq(new Bar(1)).toDS
       ds.show

       sc.stop()
     }
   }
   ```

   It stores objects as `binary` column so when converted to `DataFrame` you get following schema:

   ```
   root
    |-- value: binary (nullable = true)
   ```

   It is also possible to encode tuples using `kryo` encoder for specific field:

   ```
   val longBarEncoder = Encoders.tuple(Encoders.scalaLong, Encoders.kryo[Bar])

   spark.createDataset(Seq((1L, new Bar(1))))(longBarEncoder)
   // org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[(Long, Bar)] = [_1: bigint, _2: binary]
   ```

   Please note that we don't depend on implicit encoders here but pass encoder explicitly so this most likely won't work with `toDS` method.
2. Using implicit conversions:

   Provide implicit conversions between representation which can be encoded and custom class, for example:

   ```
   object BarConversions {
     implicit def toInt(bar: Bar): Int = bar.bar
     implicit def toBar(i: Int): Bar = new Bar(i)
   }

   object Main {
     def main(args: Array[String]) {
       val sc = new SparkContext("local",  "test", new SparkConf())
       val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
       import sqlContext.implicits._
       import BarConversions._

       type EncodedBar = Int

       val bars: RDD[EncodedBar]  = sc.parallelize(Seq(new Bar(1)))
       val barsDS = bars.toDS

       barsDS.show
       barsDS.map(_.bar).show

       sc.stop()
     }
   }
   ```

Related questions:

- [How to create encoder for Option type constructor, e.g. Option[Int]?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36449368/1560062)

Comment: Solution 1 does not seem to work for typed collections (at least `Set`)
I get `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No Encoder found for Set[Bar]`.

Comment: @VictorP. It is expected I am afraid In case like this you'll need an encoder for specific type (`kryo[Set[Bar]]`. The same way if class contains a field `Bar` you need encoder for a whole object. These are very crude methods.

Comment: @zero323 I'm facing the same issue. Can you put a code example of how to encode the whole project? Many Thanks!

Comment: @Rock I am not sure what you mean by "whole project"

Comment: @zero323 per your comment, "if class contains a field `Bar` you need encoder for a whole object". my question was how to encode this "whole project"?

Comment: @Rock Oh, you mean "whole object", right? As far as I am aware you'll need an encoder `Encoder.kryo[SomeClassThatContainsBar]`. There can be some other solutions out there though. You can for example generate tuple encoder with `Bar` field (see ` longBarEncoder` example above).

Answer (score 14):

You can use UDTRegistration and then Case Classes, Tuples, etc... all work correctly with your User Defined Type!

**Say you want to use a custom Enum:**

```
trait CustomEnum { def value:String }
case object Foo extends CustomEnum  { val value = "F" }
case object Bar extends CustomEnum  { val value = "B" }
object CustomEnum {
  def fromString(str:String) = Seq(Foo, Bar).find(_.value == str).get
}
```

Register it like this:

```
// First define a UDT class for it:
class CustomEnumUDT extends UserDefinedType[CustomEnum] {
  override def sqlType: DataType = org.apache.spark.sql.types.StringType
  override def serialize(obj: CustomEnum): Any = org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String.fromString(obj.value)
  // Note that this will be a UTF8String type
  override def deserialize(datum: Any): CustomEnum = CustomEnum.fromString(datum.toString)
  override def userClass: Class[CustomEnum] = classOf[CustomEnum]
}

// Then Register the UDT Class!
// NOTE: you have to put this file into the org.apache.spark package!
UDTRegistration.register(classOf[CustomEnum].getName, classOf[CustomEnumUDT].getName)
```

Then USE IT!

```
case class UsingCustomEnum(id:Int, en:CustomEnum)

val seq = Seq(
  UsingCustomEnum(1, Foo),
  UsingCustomEnum(2, Bar),
  UsingCustomEnum(3, Foo)
).toDS()
seq.filter(_.en == Foo).show()
println(seq.collect())
```

**Say you want to use a Polymorphic Record:**

```
trait CustomPoly
case class FooPoly(id:Int) extends CustomPoly
case class BarPoly(value:String, secondValue:Long) extends CustomPoly
```

... and the use it like this:

```
case class UsingPoly(id:Int, poly:CustomPoly)

Seq(
  UsingPoly(1, new FooPoly(1)),
  UsingPoly(2, new BarPoly("Blah", 123)),
  UsingPoly(3, new FooPoly(1))
).toDS

polySeq.filter(_.poly match {
  case FooPoly(value) => value == 1
  case _ => false
}).show()
```

You can write a custom UDT that encodes everything to bytes (I'm using java serialization here but it's probably better to instrument Spark's Kryo context).

First define the UDT class:

```
class CustomPolyUDT extends UserDefinedType[CustomPoly] {
  val kryo = new Kryo()

  override def sqlType: DataType = org.apache.spark.sql.types.BinaryType
  override def serialize(obj: CustomPoly): Any = {
    val bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    val oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos)
    oos.writeObject(obj)

    bos.toByteArray
  }
  override def deserialize(datum: Any): CustomPoly = {
    val bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(datum.asInstanceOf[Array[Byte]])
    val ois = new ObjectInputStream(bis)
    val obj = ois.readObject()
    obj.asInstanceOf[CustomPoly]
  }

  override def userClass: Class[CustomPoly] = classOf[CustomPoly]
}
```

Then register it:

```
// NOTE: The file you do this in has to be inside of the org.apache.spark package!
UDTRegistration.register(classOf[CustomPoly].getName, classOf[CustomPolyUDT].getName)
```

Then you can use it!

```
// As shown above:
case class UsingPoly(id:Int, poly:CustomPoly)

Seq(
  UsingPoly(1, new FooPoly(1)),
  UsingPoly(2, new BarPoly("Blah", 123)),
  UsingPoly(3, new FooPoly(1))
).toDS

polySeq.filter(_.poly match {
  case FooPoly(value) => value == 1
  case _ => false
}).show()
```

Comment: I don't see where your kryo is used (in CustomPolyUDT)

Comment: I am trying to define a UDT in my project and I am getting this error "Symbol UserDefinedType is inaccessible from this place". Any help ?

Comment: Hi @RijoJoseph. You need make a package org.apache.spark in your project and put your UDT code in that.

Comment: I tried this method putting my code in a package in org.apache.spark.  And called the registration.  But still get errors about  no encoder for my enum... ?

Answer (score 5):

Encoders work more or less the same in `Spark2.0`. And `Kryo` is still the recommended `serialization` choice.

You can look at following example with spark-shell

```
scala> import spark.implicits._
import spark.implicits._

scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders
import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders

scala> case class NormalPerson(name: String, age: Int) {
 |   def aboutMe = s"I am ${name}. I am ${age} years old."
 | }
defined class NormalPerson

scala> case class ReversePerson(name: Int, age: String) {
 |   def aboutMe = s"I am ${name}. I am ${age} years old."
 | }
defined class ReversePerson

scala> val normalPersons = Seq(
 |   NormalPerson("Superman", 25),
 |   NormalPerson("Spiderman", 17),
 |   NormalPerson("Ironman", 29)
 | )
normalPersons: Seq[NormalPerson] = List(NormalPerson(Superman,25), NormalPerson(Spiderman,17), NormalPerson(Ironman,29))

scala> val ds1 = sc.parallelize(normalPersons).toDS
ds1: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[NormalPerson] = [name: string, age: int]

scala> val ds2 = ds1.map(np => ReversePerson(np.age, np.name))
ds2: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[ReversePerson] = [name: int, age: string]

scala> ds1.show()
+---------+---+
|     name|age|
+---------+---+
| Superman| 25|
|Spiderman| 17|
|  Ironman| 29|
+---------+---+

scala> ds2.show()
+----+---------+
|name|      age|
+----+---------+
|  25| Superman|
|  17|Spiderman|
|  29|  Ironman|
+----+---------+

scala> ds1.foreach(p => println(p.aboutMe))
I am Ironman. I am 29 years old.
I am Superman. I am 25 years old.
I am Spiderman. I am 17 years old.

scala> val ds2 = ds1.map(np => ReversePerson(np.age, np.name))
ds2: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[ReversePerson] = [name: int, age: string]

scala> ds2.foreach(p => println(p.aboutMe))
I am 17. I am Spiderman years old.
I am 25. I am Superman years old.
I am 29. I am Ironman years old.
```

Till now] there were no `appropriate encoders` in present scope so our persons were not encoded as `binary` values. But that will change once we provide some `implicit` encoders using `Kryo` serialization.

```
// Provide Encoders

scala> implicit val normalPersonKryoEncoder = Encoders.kryo[NormalPerson]
normalPersonKryoEncoder: org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder[NormalPerson] = class[value[0]: binary]

scala> implicit val reversePersonKryoEncoder = Encoders.kryo[ReversePerson]
reversePersonKryoEncoder: org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder[ReversePerson] = class[value[0]: binary]

// Ecoders will be used since they are now present in Scope

scala> val ds3 = sc.parallelize(normalPersons).toDS
ds3: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[NormalPerson] = [value: binary]

scala> val ds4 = ds3.map(np => ReversePerson(np.age, np.name))
ds4: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[ReversePerson] = [value: binary]

// now all our persons show up as binary values
scala> ds3.show()
+--------------------+
|               value|
+--------------------+
|[01 00 24 6C 69 6...|
|[01 00 24 6C 69 6...|
|[01 00 24 6C 69 6...|
+--------------------+

scala> ds4.show()
+--------------------+
|               value|
+--------------------+
|[01 00 24 6C 69 6...|
|[01 00 24 6C 69 6...|
|[01 00 24 6C 69 6...|
+--------------------+

// Our instances still work as expected    

scala> ds3.foreach(p => println(p.aboutMe))
I am Ironman. I am 29 years old.
I am Spiderman. I am 17 years old.
I am Superman. I am 25 years old.

scala> ds4.foreach(p => println(p.aboutMe))
I am 25. I am Superman years old.
I am 29. I am Ironman years old.
I am 17. I am Spiderman years old.
```

Comment: How to convert back to normal non-binary value after using the encoders when we do a `.show`?

Answer (score 4):

In case of Java Bean class, this can be useful

```
import spark.sqlContext.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders
implicit val encoder = Encoders.bean[MyClasss](classOf[MyClass])
```

Now you can simply read the dataFrame as custom DataFrame

```
dataFrame.as[MyClass]
```

This will create a custom class encoder and not a binary one.

Answer (score 2):

*My examples will be in Java, but I don't imagine it to be difficult adapting to Scala.*

I have been quite successful converting `RDD<Fruit>` to `Dataset<Fruit>` using [spark.createDataset](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/SparkSession.html#createDataset(org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD,%20org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder)) and [Encoders.bean](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Encoders.html#bean(java.lang.Class)) as long as `Fruit` is a simple [Java Bean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans).

**Step 1: Create the simple Java Bean.**

```
public class Fruit implements Serializable {
    private String name  = "default-fruit";
    private String color = "default-color";

    // AllArgsConstructor
    public Fruit(String name, String color) {
        this.name  = name;
        this.color = color;
    }

    // NoArgsConstructor
    public Fruit() {
        this("default-fruit", "default-color");
    }

    // ...create getters and setters for above fields
    // you figure it out
}
```

I'd stick to classes with primitive types and String as fields before the DataBricks folks beef up their Encoders. *If you have a class with nested object, create another simple Java Bean with all of its fields flattened, so you can use RDD transformations to map the complex type to the simpler one.* Sure it's a little extra work, but I imagine it'll help a lot on performance working with a flat schema.

**Step 2: Get your Dataset from the RDD**

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate();
JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext();

List<Fruit> fruitList = ImmutableList.of(
    new Fruit("apple", "red"),
    new Fruit("orange", "orange"),
    new Fruit("grape", "purple"));
JavaRDD<Fruit> fruitJavaRDD = jsc.parallelize(fruitList);


RDD<Fruit> fruitRDD = fruitJavaRDD.rdd();
Encoder<Fruit> fruitBean = Encoders.bean(Fruit.class);
Dataset<Fruit> fruitDataset = spark.createDataset(rdd, bean);
```

And voila! Lather, rinse, repeat.

Comment: I'd suggest pointing out that for simple structures you'd be better served by storing them in native Spark types, rather than serializing them to a blob. They work better across the Python gateway, more transparent in Parquet, and can even be cast to structures of the same shape.

Answer (score 1):

For those who may in my situation I put my answer here, too.

To be specific,

1. I was reading 'Set typed data' from SQLContext. So original data format is DataFrame.

   `val sample = spark.sqlContext.sql("select 1 as a, collect_set(1) as b limit 1")
   sample.show()`

   `+---+---+
   |  a|  b|
   +---+---+ 
   |  1|[1]|
   +---+---+`
2. Then convert it into RDD using rdd.map() with mutable.WrappedArray type.

   `sample
     .rdd.map(r => 
      (r.getInt(0), r.getAs[mutable.WrappedArray[Int]](1).toSet))
     .collect()
     .foreach(println)`

   Result:

   `(1,Set(1))`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the suggestions already given, another option I recently discovered is that you can declare your custom class including the trait `org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.DefinedByConstructorParams`.

This works if the class has a constructor that uses types the ExpressionEncoder can understand, i.e. primitive values and standard collections. It can come in handy when you're not able to declare the class as a case class, but don't want to use Kryo to encode it every time it's included in a Dataset.

For example, I wanted to declare a case class that included a Breeze vector. The only encoder that would be able to handle that would normally be Kryo. But if I declared a subclass that extended the Breeze DenseVector and DefinedByConstructorParams, the ExpressionEncoder understood that it could be serialized as an array of Doubles.

Here's how I declared it:

```
class SerializableDenseVector(values: Array[Double]) extends breeze.linalg.DenseVector[Double](values) with DefinedByConstructorParams
implicit def BreezeVectorToSerializable(bv: breeze.linalg.DenseVector[Double]): SerializableDenseVector = bv.asInstanceOf[SerializableDenseVector]
```

Now I can use `SerializableDenseVector` in a Dataset (directly, or as part of a Product) using a simple ExpressionEncoder and no Kryo. It works just like a Breeze DenseVector but serializes as an Array[Double].

Answer (score 0):

@Alec's answer is great! Just to add a comment in this part of his/her answer:

```
import spark.implicits._
case class Wrap[T](unwrap: T)
class MyObj(val i: Int)
// ...
val d = spark.createDataset(Seq(Wrap(new MyObj(1)),Wrap(new MyObj(2)),Wrap(new MyObj(3))))
```

@Alec mentions:

> there is no way of passing in custom encoders for nested types (I have no way of feeding Spark an encoder for just MyObj such that it then knows how to encode Wrap[MyObj] or (Int,MyObj)).

It seems so, because if I add an encoder for `MyObj`:

```
implicit val myEncoder = org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders.kryo[MyObj]
```

, it still fails:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No Encoder found for MyObj
- field (class: "MyObj", name: "unwrap")
- root class: "Wrap"
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$ScalaReflection$$serializerFor$1.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:643)
```

But notice the important error message:

> root class: "Wrap"

It actually gives a hint that encoding `MyObj` isn't enough, and you have to encode the **entire chain** including `Wrap[T]`.

So if I do this, it **solves the problem**:

```
implicit val myWrapperEncoder = org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders.kryo[Wrap[MyObj]]
```

Hence, the comment of @Alec is **NOT** that true:

> I have no way of feeding Spark an encoder for just MyObj such that it then knows how to encode Wrap[MyObj] or (Int,MyObj)

We still **have a way to feed Spark the encoder for `MyObj`** such that it then knows how to encode Wrap[MyObj] or (Int,MyObj).