# No Java class corresponding to Product with Serializable with Base found

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, rdd, apache-spark-dataset

I've written `two case class` that extends Base `abstract class`. I have two list of each class (`listA` and `listB`). When I want to merge these two list, I can't convert the final list to Apache Spark 1.6.1 Dataset.

```
abstract class Base

case class A(name: String) extends Base
case class B(age: Int) extends Base

val listA: List[A] = A("foo")::A("bar")::Nil
val listB: List[B] = B(10)::B(20)::Nil
val list: List[Base with Product with Serializable] = listA ++ listB

val result: RDD[Base with Product with Serializable] = sc.parallelize(list).toDS()
```

Apache Spark will rise this Exception:

```
A needed class was not found. This could be due to an error in your runpath. Missing class: no Java class corresponding to Base with Product with Serializable found
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: no Java class corresponding to Base with Product with Serializable found
    at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror.typeToJavaClass(JavaMirrors.scala:1299)
    at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror.runtimeClass(JavaMirrors.scala:192)
    at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror.runtimeClass(JavaMirrors.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder$.apply(ExpressionEncoder.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLImplicits.newProductEncoder(SQLImplicits.scala:41)
```

When I want to create RDD from `list` Spark doesn't throw any Exception, But when I convert RDD to Dataset with `toDS()` method this prior exception will throw.

Comment: I'm not sure mixins are supported yet with DataSet encoders.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you can get a saner type for `list` by making it a `List[Base]` explicitly or by adding `Base extends Product with Serializable` if the intention is for it only to be extended by case classes/objects. But this isn't enough, because

> [Spark 1.6 comes with support for automatically generating encoders for a wide variety of types, including primitive types (e.g. String, Integer, Long), Scala case classes, and Java Beans.](https://databricks.com/blog/2016/01/04/introducing-apache-spark-datasets.html)

Note that abstract classes like `Base` are not supported. And custom encoders aren't supported either. Though you could try using the `kryo` (or `javaSerialization`, as the last resort) encoder, see [How to store custom objects in Dataset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36648128/how-to-store-custom-objects-in-a-dataset-in-spark-1-6).

Here is complete working example:

```
abstract class Base extends Serializable with Product

case class A(name: String) extends Base

case class B(age: Int) extends Base

object BaseEncoder {
  implicit def baseEncoder: org.apache.spark.Encoder[Base] = org.apache.spark.Encoders.kryo[Base]
}


val listA: Seq[A] = Seq(A("a"), A("b"))
val listB: Seq[B] = Seq(B(1), B(2))
val list: Seq[Base] = listA ++ listB

val ds = sc.parallelize(list).toDS
```

Comment: tait solution didn't work, but writing Encoder works very well.

Comment: The second paragraph actually explains why the first isn't enough. I fixed the text to make it more clear.

Comment: So that Scala doesn't end up inferring `Base with Product` if you don't specify type for `list` (or elsewhere). Do you mean it fails to work if `with Product` is added?