# How to create a Spark Dataset from an RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataset, apache-spark-dataset

I have an `RDD[LabeledPoint]` intended to be used within a machine learning pipeline.  How do we convert that `RDD` to a `DataSet`?  Note the newer  `spark.ml` apis require inputs in the `Dataset` format.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here is an answer that traverses an extra step - the `DataFrame`.   We use the `SQLContext` to create a `DataFrame` and then create a `DataSet` using the desired object type - in this case a `LabeledPoint`:

```scala
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
val pointsTrainDf =  sqlContext.createDataFrame(training)
val pointsTrainDs = pointsTrainDf.as[LabeledPoint]
```

**Update**  Ever heard of a **`SparkSession`** ?  (neither had I until now..)

So apparently the `SparkSession` is the *Preferred Way* (TM) in Spark 2.0.0 and moving forward.  Here is the updated code for the new (spark) world order:

**Spark 2.0.0+ approaches**

Notice in both of the below approaches (simpler one of which credit @zero323) we have accomplished an important savings as compared to the `SQLContext` approach: no longer is it necessary to first create a `DataFrame`.

```scala
val sparkSession =  SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()
val pointsTrainDf =  sparkSession.createDataset(training)
val model = new LogisticRegression()
   .train(pointsTrainDs.as[LabeledPoint])
```

**Second way for Spark 2.0.0+**  Credit to @zero323

```
val spark: org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession = ???
import spark.implicits._

val trainDs = training.toDS()
```

**Traditional Spark 1.X and earlier approach**

```
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)  // Note this is *deprecated* in 2.0.0
import sqlContext.implicits._
val training = splits(0).cache()
val test = splits(1)
val trainDs = training**.toDS()**
```

See also: [How to store custom objects in Dataset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36648128/how-to-store-custom-objects-in-a-dataset-in-spark-1-6) by the esteemed @zero323 .

Comment: How about `training.toDS`?

Comment: @zero323  ah, I see I need to `import sqlContext._`.Updating the answer.

Comment: @zero323 You have added sufficient info - feel free to add your own answer

Comment: You're gonna complain there is no fun in answering if I do :D To be serious I don't much to add and a single consistent reference is much better.

Comment: @zero323 So you noticed that comment from a week ago . I was concerned you were taking it too seriously ;).  It was meant as respect for your knowledge. You also have a v nice approach/attitude.

Comment: Me nice? You must have mistaken me with my good twin :) BTW: it could be a good idea to link http://stackoverflow.com/q/36648128/1560062 here.