# Spark Error: Unable to find encoder for type stored in a Dataset

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset, apache-spark-encoders

I am using Spark on a Zeppelin notebook, and groupByKey() does not seem to be working.

This code:

```
df.groupByKey(row => row.getLong(0))
  .mapGroups((key, iterable) => println(key))
```

Gives me this error (presumably a compilation error, since it shows up in no time while the dataset I am working on is pretty big):

```
error: Unable to find encoder for type stored in a Dataset.  Primitive types (Int, String, etc) and Product types (case classes) are supported by importing spark.implicits._  Support for serializing other types will be added in future releases.
```

I tried to add a case class and map all of my rows into it, but still got the same error

```
import spark.implicits._

case class DFRow(profileId: Long, jobId: String, state: String)

def getDFRow(row: Row):DFRow = {
    return DFRow(row.getLong(row.fieldIndex("item0")),
                 row.getString(row.fieldIndex("item1")), 
                 row.getString(row.fieldIndex("item2")))
}

df.map(DFRow(_))
  .groupByKey(row => row.getLong(0))
  .mapGroups((key, iterable) => println(key))
```

The schema of my Dataframe is:

```
root
|-- item0: long (nullable = true)
|-- item1: string (nullable = true)
|-- item2: string (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're trying to `mapGroups` with a function `(Long, Iterator[Row]) => Unit` and there is no `Encoder` for `Unit` (not that it would make sense to have one).

In general parts of the `Dataset` API which are not focused on the SQL DSL (`DataFrame => DataFrame`, `DataFrame => RelationalGroupedDataset`, `RelationalGroupedDataset => DataFrame`, `RelationalGroupedDataset => RelationalGroupedDataset`) require either implicit or explicit encoders for the output values.

Since there are no predefined encoders for `Row` objects, using `Dataset[Row]` with methods design for statically typed data doesn't make much sense. As a rule of thumb you should always convert to the statically typed variant first:

```
df.as[(Long, String, String)]
```

See also [Encoder error while trying to map dataframe row to updated row](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39433419/1560062)

Comment: Thank you for your complete answer, @zero323. I am currently picking up Spark, and your introduction to `Encoder`s was of great help even though the question was dumb. One quick question, though, is how can I perform computations and get a basic data type like `List` given that no encoders exist for that?

Comment: For starters take a look at https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#data-types. If something is in the table you're fixed. Case classes are handled out of the box as well as long as fields correspond to SQL types. The rest: http://stackoverflow.com/q/36648128/1560062