# spark udaf update array type of tuple

Tags: arrays, scala, apache-spark, aggregate-functions, user-defined-functions

I'm using Scala + Spark 2.0 and trying to write an UDAF that has an Array of tuples as its internal buffer as well as its return type:
...

```
def bufferSchema = new StructType().add("midResults", ArrayType(  StructType(Array(StructField("a", DoubleType),StructField("b", DoubleType))) ))

def dataType: DataType = ArrayType(  StructType(Array(StructField( "a", DoubleType),StructField("b", DoubleType))) )
```

And this is how I update the buffer

```
def update(buffer: MutableAggregationBuffer, input: Row) = {
buffer(0) = buffer.getAs[mutable.WrappedArray[(Double,Double)]](3) ++ Array((3.0,4.0))
}
```

But I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.ArrayStoreException: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema
```

This pattern works if I have a simple Array of Double..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`java.lang.ArrayStoreException` is [*"thrown to indicate that an attempt has been made to store the wrong type of object into an array of objects"*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayStoreException.html) and this expected [because a local Scala type for `StructType` is `o.a.s.sql.Row`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#data-types) not a tuple. In other words you should use a `Seq[Row]` as a buffer field and `Row` as a value.

**Notes**:

- Calling `++` in a loop is probably not the best idea ever.
- Creating an UDAF is slightly obsolete if you consider that since Spark 2.0 `collect_list` supports complex types.
- Arguably [`Aggregators`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Aggregator) are way more user friendly than the `UserDefinedAggregateFunctions`.

Comment: Not sure I agree that it is trying to store a Row in this case, but I will definitely switch to collect_list and Aggregators (UDAF is a bit clunky, I agree). Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: A bit is an understatement :) `Aggregators` are still quite verbose but much more pleasant to write. Regarding rows you cannot have schema of type `TupleN`. Reflection here works only one way. So buffer should contain `Seq[Row]` and function should expect `Rows` as an input.

Comment: After trying out the example I get an issue with finding the automagic Encoders. I added  "import sparkSession.implicits._"  Any other pointers?

Comment: `Aggregators`? Keep in mind that API changed between 1.6 and 2.0. I have a full 2.0 example here https://stackoverflow.com/a/32101530/1560062. Of course you should convert `DataFrame` to some statically typed Dataset first. Otherwise you'll have to deal with RowEncoders: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39433419/1560062.

Comment: I do not understand how this solves trying to use a tuple in a buffer...