# Reading Avro messages from Kafka with Spark 2.0.2 (structured streaming)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, avro, spark-structured-streaming

I have a spark 2.0 application that reads messages from kafka using spark streaming (with spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11).

Structured streaming looks really cool so I wanted to try and migrate the code but I can't figure out how to use it.

in the regular streaming I used kafkaUtils to createDstrean and in the parameters I passed it was the value deserializer.

in the Structured streaming the doc says that I should deserialize using DataFrame functions but I can't figure exactly what that means.

I looked at examples such as this [example](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/structured-streaming/kafka.html) but my Avro object in Kafka is quit complex and cannot be simply casted like the String in the example..

So far I tried this kind of code (which I saw here in a different question):

```
import spark.implicits._

  val ds1 = spark.readStream.format("kafka").
    option("kafka.bootstrap.servers","localhost:9092").
    option("subscribe","RED-test-tal4").load()

  ds1.printSchema()
  ds1.select("value").printSchema()
  val ds2 = ds1.select($"value".cast(getDfSchemaFromAvroSchema(Obj.getClassSchema))).show()  
  val query = ds2.writeStream
    .outputMode("append")
    .format("console")
    .start()
```

and I get "data type mismatch: cannot cast BinaryType to StructType(StructField(...."

how can I deserialize the value?

Comment: Did someone find a working solution? None of the below are working for me!

Comment: This library supports structured streams with Avro as a payload and may help: [ABRiS (Avro Bridge for Spark)](https://github.com/AbsaOSS/ABRiS). It still is under development but supports your use case. DISCLOSURE: I work for ABSA and I am the main developer behind this library.

Answer (score 4):

As noted above, as of Spark 2.1.0 there is support for avro with the batch reader but not with SparkSession.readStream(). Here is how I got it to work in Scala based on the other responses. I've simplified the schema for brevity.

```scala
package com.sevone.sparkscala.mypackage

import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.avro.io.DecoderFactory
import org.apache.avro.Schema
import org.apache.avro.generic.{GenericDatumReader, GenericRecord}

object MyMain {

    // Create avro schema and reader
    case class KafkaMessage (
        deviceId: Int,
        deviceName: String
    )
    val schemaString = """{
        "fields": [
            { "name":  "deviceId",      "type": "int"},
            { "name":  "deviceName",    "type": "string"},
        ],
        "name": "kafkamsg",
        "type": "record"
    }"""
    val messageSchema = new Schema.Parser().parse(schemaString)
    val reader = new GenericDatumReader[GenericRecord](messageSchema)
    // Factory to deserialize binary avro data
    val avroDecoderFactory = DecoderFactory.get()
    // Register implicit encoder for map operation
    implicit val encoder: Encoder[GenericRecord] = org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders.kryo[GenericRecord]

    def main(args: Array[String]) {

        val KafkaBroker =  args(0);
        val InTopic = args(1);
        val OutTopic = args(2);

        // Get Spark session
        val session = SparkSession
                .builder
                .master("local[*]")
                .appName("myapp")
                .getOrCreate()

        // Load streaming data
        import session.implicits._
        val data = session
                .readStream
                .format("kafka")
                .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", KafkaBroker)
                .option("subscribe", InTopic)
                .load()
                .select($"value".as[Array[Byte]])
                .map(d => {
                    val rec = reader.read(null, avroDecoderFactory.binaryDecoder(d, null))
                    val deviceId = rec.get("deviceId").asInstanceOf[Int]
                    val deviceName = rec.get("deviceName").asInstanceOf[org.apache.avro.util.Utf8].toString
                    new KafkaMessage(deviceId, deviceName)
                })
```

Comment: it didnt worked for me ,Caused by: java.io.EOFException error

Comment: This solution doesn't worked for schema registry enabled kafka. It reported "Caused by: org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException: Malformed data. Length is negative: -13"

Comment: Make sure the avro schema used here matches word to word with the schema from kafka.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not yet super familiar how Spark's serialization works in combination with the new/experimental Structured Streaming, but the approach below does work -- though I am not sure if it's the best way (IMHO the approach has a somewhat awkward look 'n feel).

I'll try to answer your question at the example of a custom data type (here: a `Foo` case class) instead of specifically Avro, but I hope it'll help you anyways.  The idea is to use Kryo serialization to serialize/deserialize your custom type, see [Tuning: Data serialization](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html#data-serialization) in the Spark documentation.

> Note: Spark supports serialization of case classes out of the box via built-in (implicit) encoders that you can import via `import spark.implicits._`.  But let's ignore this functionality for the sake of this example.

Imagine you have defined the following `Foo` case class as your custom type (TL;DR hint: to prevent running into weird Spark serialization complaints/errors you should put the code into a separate `Foo.scala` file):

```
// This could also be your auto-generated Avro class/type
case class Foo(s: String)
```

Now you have the following Structured Streaming code to read data from Kafka, where the input topic contains Kafka messages whose message value is a binary-encoded `String`, and your goal is it to create `Foo` instances based on these message values (i.e. similar to how you'd deserialize binary data into instances of an Avro class):

```
val messages: DataFrame = spark.readStream
    .format("kafka")
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "broker1:9092,broker2:9092")
    .option("subscribe", "my-input-topic")
    .load()
```

Now we are [deserializing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39442829/1743580) the values into instances of our custom `Foo` type, for which we first need to define an implicit `Encoder[Foo]`:

```
implicit val myFooEncoder: Encoder[Foo] = org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders.kryo[Foo]
val foos: Dataset[Foo] = messages.map(row => Foo(new String(row.getAs[Array[Byte]]("value")))
```

Going back to your Avro question, what you'd need to do is to:

1. Create a proper `Encoder` for your needs.
2. Replace `Foo(new String(row.getAs[Array[Byte]]("value"))` with the code to deserialize your binary-encoded Avro data into Avro POJOs, i.e. code that takes your binary-encoded Avro data out of the message value (`row.getAs[Array[Byte]]("value")`) and returns, say, an Avro `GenericRecord` or whatever `SpecificCustomAvroObject` you have defined elsewhere.

If someone else knows of a more concise/better/... way to answer Tal's question, I'm all ears. :-)

See also:

- [How to store custom objects in Dataset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36648128/how-to-store-custom-objects-in-a-dataset)
- [Encoder error while trying to map dataframe row to updated row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39433419/encoder-error-while-trying-to-map-dataframe-row-to-updated-row)

Comment: I think Tal's use case is that he does not have binary encoded String on his topic, he has binary encoded avro. Would using bijection-avro work in this case?

Comment: yep @zzztimbo that's right.. I had to backlog this project a little so I havn't had a chance to try anything new.. hopefully I'll look into this subject soon. when I'll do I'll look into bijection-avro

Comment: @TalJoffe please let me know what you come up with. I'm trying to read avro that was put there by a kstream and bijection-avro didn't work out for me.

Comment: @zzztimbo oh o.k. as I said it might take me a while but once I figure it out I'll right here

Answer (score 3):

So actually someone in my firm solved this for me So I'll post it here for future readers..

basically what I missed on top of what miguno suggested is the decode part:

```
def decodeMessages(iter: Iterator[KafkaMessage], schemaRegistryUrl: String) : Iterator[<YourObject>] = {
val decoder = AvroTo<YourObject>Decoder.getDecoder(schemaRegistryUrl)
iter.map(message => {
  val record = decoder.fromBytes(message.value).asInstanceOf[GenericData.Record]
  val field1 = record.get("field1Name").asInstanceOf[GenericData.Record]
  val field2 = record.get("field1Name").asInstanceOf[GenericData.String]
        ...
  //create an object with the fields extracted from genericRecord
  })
}
```

now you can read messages from kafka and decode them like so:

```
val ds = spark
  .readStream
  .format(config.getString(ConfigUtil.inputFormat))
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", config.getString(ConfigUtil.kafkaBootstrapServers))
  .option("subscribe", config.getString(ConfigUtil.subscribeTopic))
  .load()
  .as[KafkaMessage]

val decodedDs  = ds.mapPartitions(decodeMessages(_, schemaRegistryUrl))
```

*`KafkaMessage` is simply a case class that contains the generic object you get when reading from Kafka `(key,value,topic,partition,offset,timestamp)`

`AvroTo<YourObject>Decoder` is some class that'll decode your object given a schema registry url.

For example using Confluent's [`KafkaAvroDeserializer`](https://docs.confluent.io/current/app-development.html#java) and schema registry.

```
val kafkaProps = Map("schema.registry.url" -> schemaRegistryUrl)
val client = new CachedSchemaRegistryClient(schemaRegistryUrl, 20)

// If you have Avro encoded keys
val keyDeserializer = new KafkaAvroDeserializer(client)
keyDeserializer.configure(kafkaProps.asJava, true) //isKey = true

// Avro encoded values
valueDeserializer = new KafkaAvroDeserializer(client)
valueDeserializer.configure(kafkaProps.asJava, false) //isKey = false
```

From these, call `.deserialize(topicName, bytes).asInstanceOf[GenericRecord]` to get an avro object.

Hope this helps someone

Comment: So do you mean we need provide related case class besides avro generated class? Could you show us your import statement? Where to get the "Deocder" class in this statement?
val decoder = AvroTo<YourObject>Decoder.getDecoder(schemaRegistryUrl)

Answer (score 2):

Use the following steps:

- Define a Kafka message.
- Define a consumer Utility, which returns a DataSet of YourAvroObject.
- Define your logical code.

---

Kafka Message:

```
case class KafkaMessage(key: String, value: Array[Byte],
                                    topic: String, partition: String, offset: Long, timestamp: Timestamp)
```

Kafka Consumer:

```
import java.util.Collections

import com.typesafe.config.{Config, ConfigFactory}
import io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer
import org.apache.avro.Schema
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._


object KafkaAvroConsumer {

  private val conf: Config = ConfigFactory.load().getConfig("kafka.consumer")
  val valueDeserializer = new KafkaAvroDeserializer()
  valueDeserializer.configure(Collections.singletonMap("schema.registry.url",
    conf.getString("schema.registry.url")), false)

  def transform[T <: GenericRecord : TypeTag](msg: KafkaMessage, schemaStr: String) = {
    val schema = new Schema.Parser().parse(schemaStr)
    Utils.convert[T](schema)(valueDeserializer.deserialize(msg.topic, msg.value))
  }

  def createDataStream[T <: GenericRecord with Product with Serializable : TypeTag]
  (schemaStr: String)
  (subscribeType: String, topics: String, appName: String, startingOffsets: String = "latest") = {

    val spark = SparkSession
      .builder
      .master("local[*]")
      .appName(appName)
      .getOrCreate()

    import spark.implicits._

    // Create DataSet representing the stream of KafkaMessage from kafka
    val ds = spark
      .readStream
      .format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", conf.getString("bootstrap.servers"))
      .option(subscribeType, topics)
      .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
      .load()
      .as[KafkaMessage]
      .map(msg => KafkaAvroConsumer.transform[T](msg, schemaStr)) // Transform it Avro object.

    ds
  }

}
```

*Update*

Utils:

```
import org.apache.avro.Schema
import org.apache.avro.file.DataFileReader
import org.apache.avro.generic.{GenericDatumReader, GenericRecord}
import org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificData

import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

object Utils {


  def convert[T <: GenericRecord: TypeTag](targetSchema: Schema)(record: AnyRef): T = {
      SpecificData.get.deepCopy(targetSchema, record).asInstanceOf[T]
  }


}
```

Comment: Can you please give full example or share the code in github

Comment: How does Utils.convert method define?

Comment: What is a `TypeTag`? What if you don't want to hard-code a reader schema string and what to use the Schema ID within the message?

Comment: @CaselChen, I have added the utility function, I hope that it will help you. 
Sorry but it's an old code & i didn't kept the repository.

Comment: @cricket_007, please read about schema registry & Schema evolution. The schema is not hard coded.
https://docs.oracle.com/database/nosql-11.2.2.0/GettingStartedGuide/schemaevolution.html

Comment: I know about Schema Evolution. That wasn't my comment. I also know about the schema registry. My question was about your parameter `schemaStr`... This should not be necessary, as the `KafkaAvroDeserializer` class is able to detect the Magic Byte + Schema ID that Confluent's Avro encoding is using, then does a lookup against the registry for that schema string. In other words, I think it should be possible to not "hard code" a reader schema string, and let it be dynamically extracted from the registry

Comment: @cricket_007, you are right. the schemaStr is used for transformation.

Comment: I guess my question is why you need it, or where in this example you'd define it? I can understand if you used the client to get the latest schema that's backwards compatible, but then you already have a schema object. No need to parse a string

Comment: Let's assume you have a component, which produce an object with schema s1 and some of the consumers need different view on that data (e.g. some may use s1, and others may use s2, s3 & s4).You may use the schema evolution as a mechanism for that. Of course, it's not always a good idea.