# Encoder for Row Type Spark Datasets

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset, apache-spark-encoders

I would like to write an encoder for a [Row](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/sql/Row.html) type in DataSet, for a map operation that I am doing. Essentially, I do not understand how to write encoders.

Below is an example of a map operation:

`In the example below, instead of returning Dataset<String>, I would like to return Dataset<Row>`

```
Dataset<String> output = dataset1.flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<Row, String>() {
            @Override
            public Iterator<String> call(Row row) throws Exception {

                ArrayList<String> obj = //some map operation
                return obj.iterator();
            }
        },Encoders.STRING());
```

I understand that instead of a string Encoder needs to be written as follows:

```
    Encoder<Row> encoder = new Encoder<Row>() {
        @Override
        public StructType schema() {
            return join.schema();
            //return null;
        }

        @Override
        public ClassTag<Row> clsTag() {
            return null;
        }
    };
```

However, I do not understand the clsTag() in the encoder, and I am trying to find a running example which can demostrate something similar (i.e. an encoder for a row type)

Edit - This is not a copy of the question mentioned : [Encoder error while trying to map dataframe row to updated row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39433419/encoder-error-while-trying-to-map-dataframe-row-to-updated-row) as the answer talks about using Spark 1.x in Spark 2.x (I am not doing so), also I am looking for an encoder for a Row class rather than resolve an error. Finally, I was looking for a solution in Java, not in Scala.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The answer is to use a [RowEncoder](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-RowEncoder.html) and the schema of the dataset using [StructType](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/types/StructType.html).

Below is a working example of a flatmap operation with Datasets:

```
    StructType structType = new StructType();
    structType = structType.add("id1", DataTypes.LongType, false);
    structType = structType.add("id2", DataTypes.LongType, false);

    ExpressionEncoder<Row> encoder = RowEncoder.apply(structType);

    Dataset<Row> output = join.flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<Row, Row>() {
        @Override
        public Iterator<Row> call(Row row) throws Exception {
            // a static map operation to demonstrate
            List<Object> data = new ArrayList<>();
            data.add(1l);
            data.add(2l);
            ArrayList<Row> list = new ArrayList<>();
            list.add(RowFactory.create(data.toArray()));
            return list.iterator();
        }
    }, encoder);
```

Comment: shouldn't this fail in cluster mode because ArrayList is not serializable

Comment: In Spark 3.5, I had to use `RowEncoder.encoderFor` instead of `RowEncoder.apply`

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem... `Encoders.kryo(Row.class))` worked for me.

As a bonus, the Apache Spark tuning docs refer to Kryo it since it’s faster at serialization "often as much as 10x":

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html

Comment: Doesn't that break columnar storage if you serialize the dataset to a Parquet file, though?

Comment: What's the difference between using `kryo` encoder and the `RowEncoder`, considering both works?

Comment: isn't kryo supposed to be a fallback encoder?, Kryo is a generalized encoder,and custom row encoders should perform better performance (basically allowing you to code for more optimized encoding for your schema), as far as i remember, please correct if i'm missing something