# Apache Spark - Map function returning empty dataset in java

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset, apache-spark-2.0

**My Code:**

```
finalJoined.show();

Encoder<Row> rowEncoder = Encoders.bean(Row.class);                             
Dataset<Row> validatedDS = finalJoined.map(row -> validationRowMap(row), rowEncoder);       
validatedDS.show();
```

**Map function :**

```
public static Row validationRowMap(Row row) {

        //PART-A validateTxn()

        System.out.println("Inside map");
        //System.out.println("Value of CIS_DIVISION is " + row.getString(7));

        //1. CIS_DIVISION
        if ((row.getString(7)) == null || (row.getString(7)).trim().isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("CIS_DIVISION cannot be blank.");
        }

return row;

}
```

**Output :**

**finalJoined** `Dataset<Row>` is properly shown with all columns and rows with proper values, however **validatedDS** `Dataset<Row>`is shown with only one column with empty values.

***Expected output : ***

**validatedDS** should also show same values as **finalJoined** dataset because I am only performing validation inside the map function and not changing the dataset itself.

Please let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 1):

`Encoders.bean` is intended for usage with Bean classes. `Row` is not one of these (doesn't define setter and getters for specific fields, only generic getters).

To return `Row` object you have to use `RowEncoder` and provide expected output schema.

Check for example [Encoder for Row Type Spark Datasets](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43238693/8371915)