# What's the difference between Dataset.map(r=>xx) and Dataframe.map(r=>xx) in Spark2.0?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

Some how in Spark2.0, I can use `Dataframe.map(r => r.getAs[String]("field"))` without problems

But `DataSet.map(r => r.getAs[String]("field"))` gives error that `r` doesn't have the "getAs" method.

What's the difference between `r` in `DataSet` and `r` in `DataFrame` and why `r.getAs` only works with `DataFrame`?

After doing some research in StackOverflow, I found a helpful answer here

> [Encoder error while trying to map dataframe row to updated row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39433419/encoder-error-while-trying-to-map-dataframe-row-to-updated-row)

Hope it's helpful

Comment: what is they type of your dataset?  `getAs` is a method on `Row` so you could only use `r.getAs` is `r` is a `Row` (ie, your dataset is a `DataSet[Row]`, notice that `DataFrame` is just an alias for `DataSet[Row]`)

Comment: Thanks. I used Dataset[_]. When I do DataSet.map( r => xx), what is r? Is it a row of data? @puhlen

Comment: No, `r` is `Any` because you didn't specify it's type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Dataset` has a type parameter: `class Dataset[T]`. `T` is the type of each record in the Dataset. That `T` might be anything (well, anything for which you can provide an implicit `Encoder[T]`, but that's besides the point).

A `map` operation on a `Dataset` applies the provided function to each record, so the `r` in the map operations you showed will have the type `T`.

Lastly, `DataFrame` is actually just an alias for `Dataset[Row]`, which means each record has the type `Row`. And `Row` has a method named `getAs` that takes a type parameter and a String argument, hence you can call `getAs[String]("field")` on any `Row`. For any `T` that doesn't have this method - this will fail to compile.