# Spark - recursive function as udf generates an Exception

Tags: scala, apache-spark, recursion, apache-spark-sql

I am working with DataFrames which elements have got a schema similar to:

```
root
 |-- NPAData: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- NPADetails: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- location: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- manager: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- service: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- serviceName: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- serviceCode: string (nullable = true) 
 |-- NPAHeader: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- npaNumber: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- date: string (nullable = true)
```

In my DataFrame I want to group all elements which has the same `NPAHeader.code`, so to do that I am using the following line:

```
val groupedNpa = orderedNpa.groupBy($"NPAHeader.code" ).agg(collect_list(struct($"NPAData",$"NPAHeader")).as("npa"))
```

After this I have a dataframe with the following schema:

```
StructType(StructField(npaNumber,StringType,true), StructField(npa,ArrayType(StructType(StructField(NPAData...)))))
```

An example of each Row would be something similar to:

```
[1234,WrappedArray([npaNew,npaOlder,...npaOldest])]
```

Now what I want is to generate another DataFrame with picks up just one of the element in the WrappedArray, so I want an output similar to:

```
[1234,npaNew]
```

Note: The chosen element from the WrappedArray is the one that matches a complext logic after iterating over the whole WrappedArray. But to simplify the question, I will pick up always the last element of the WrappedArray (**after iterating** all over it).

To do so, I want to define a recurside udf

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf

def returnRow(elementList : Row)(index:Int): Row = {
  val dif = elementList.size - index
  val row :Row = dif match{
    case 0 => elementList.getAs[Row](index)
    case _ => returnRow(elementList)(index + 1) 
  }
  row
} 

val returnRow_udf = udf(returnRow _)


groupedNpa.map{row => (row.getAs[String]("npaNumber"),returnRow_udf(groupedNpa("npa")(0)))}
```

But I am getting the following error in the map:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException:
>   Schema for type Int => Unit is not supported

What am I doing wrong?

As an aside, I am not sure if I am passing correctly the `npa` column with `groupedNpa("npa")`. I am accesing the WrappedArray as a Row, because I don't know how to iterate over `Array[Row]` (the `get(index)` method is not present in Array[Row])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR** Just use one of the methods described in [How to select the first row of each group?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33878370/6910411)

If you want to use complex logic, and return `Row` you can skip SQL API and use `groupByKey`:

```
val f: (String, Iterator[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]) => Row
val encoder: Encoder 
df.groupByKey(_.getAs[String]("NPAHeader.code")).mapGroups(f)(encoder)
```

or better:

```
val g: (Row, Row) => Row

df.groupByKey(_.getAs[String]("NPAHeader.code")).reduceGroups(g)
```

where `encoder` is a valid `RowEncoder` ([Encoder error while trying to map dataframe row to updated row](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39433419/6910411)).

Your code is faulty in multiple ways:

- `groupBy` doesn't guarantee the order of values. So:

  ```
  orderBy(...).groupBy(....).agg(collect_list(...))
  ```

  can have non-deterministic output. If you really decide to go this route you should skip `orderBy` and sort collected array explicitly.
- You cannot pass curried function to `udf`. You'd have to uncurry it first, but it would require different order of arguments (see example below).
- If you could, this might be the correct way to call it (Note that you omit the second argument):

  ```
  returnRow_udf(groupedNpa("npa")(0))
  ```

  To make it worse, you call it inside `map`, where `udfs` are not applicable at all.
- `udf` cannot return `Row`. It has to return [external Scala type](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#data-types).
- External representation for `array<struct>` is `Seq[Row]`. You cannot just substitute it with `Row`.
- SQL arrays can be accessed by index with `apply`:

  ```
  df.select($"array"(size($"array") - 1))
  ```

  but it is not a correct method due to non-determinism. You could apply `sort_array`, but as pointed out at the beginning, there are more efficient solutions.
- Surprisingly recursion is not so relevant. You could design function like this:

  ```
  def size(i: Int=0)(xs: Seq[Any]): Int = xs match {
    case Seq() => i
    case null => i
    case Seq(h, t @ _*) => size(i + 1)(t)
  }

  val size_ = udf(size() _)
  ```

  and it would work just fine:

  ```
  Seq((1, Seq("a", "b", "c"))).toDF("id", "array")
    .select(size_($"array"))
  ```

  although recursion is an overkill, if you can just iterate over `Seq`.

Comment: I tried change my code as much as possible following your instructions, but I was forced to move up to some of my original approaches, because the server where I need to run this has Spark 1.6, and as I understand groupByKey, mapGroups and reduceGroups, which were going to easy my life a lot, can't be used in that version.

Comment: Here is the new one in case you want to checl. https://stackoverflow.com/q/46463931/1773841 I did several updates, that is why I prefer to ask a different question than updating here again and again. I add the partitionBy and orderBy inside a Window() to avoid the issue you pointed out. Instead of udf I use a "normal" function that hopefully I will be able to invoke from a map so I will not have the restrictions in the return type. I know this things can be done with RDD, but I am not so optimist about DF.