# Spark - I get a java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException when I invoke a custom function from a map

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a DataFrame with a structure similar to:

```
root
 |-- NPAData: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- NPADetails: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- location: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- manager: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- service: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- serviceName: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- serviceCode: string (nullable = true) 
 |-- NPAHeader: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- npaNumber: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- date: string (nullable = true)
```

What I am trying is to:

- Group the records which has got the same `npaNumber` into a list
- Inside each list, order the elements depending on their `date`
- Once I have the elements grouped and ordered, I need merge the
  elements applying some logic. To perform this list step I decided to
  use a map.

Here is what I tried so far:

```
val toUpdate = sourceDF.withColumn("count", count($"NPAHeader").over(Window.partitionBy("NPAHeader.npaNumber").orderBy($"NPAHeader.date".desc))).filter($"count" > 1)

val groupedNpa = toUpdate.groupBy($"NPAHeader.npaNumber" ).agg(collect_list(struct($"NPAData",$"NPAHeader")).as("npa"))

//This is a simply version of my logic.                                                                                                 
def pickOne(List: Seq[Row]): Row = {
      println("First element: "+List.get(0))
      List.get(0)
}

val mergedNpa = groupedNpa.map(row => (row.getAs[String]("npaNumber"),pickOne(row.getAs[Seq[Row]]("npa"))))
```

An example of a Row after the groupBy would be:

> [1234,WrappedArray([npaNew,npaOlder,...npaOldest])]

But I am getting an exception when I try to invoke the function from the map.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No
>   Encoder found for org.apache.spark.sql.Row
>   - field (class: "org.apache.spark.sql.Row", name: "_2")
>   - root class: "scala.Tuple2"

What I understand is I can not invoke the function `pickOne()` from the map (Or at least not in the way I am trying it). But I don't know what am I doing wrong.

Why am I having that exception?

Thanks for your time!

**Note**: I know there are easier ways to pick up one element from the list without invoking the custom function. But I need to invoke it yes or yes, because in the next step I need to place there a far more complex logic to merge rows.

After using Mahesh Chand Kandpal suggestion:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.RowEncoder

grouped.map(row => "emdNumber: "+row.getAs[String]("emdNumber"))
val mergedNpa = groupedNpa.map(row => (row.getAs[String]("npaNumber"),pickOne(row.getAs[Seq[Row]]("npa"))(RowEncoder(row.schema))))
```

I get the following error:

> type mismatch; found :
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]
>   required: Int

How should I apply the Encoder instead?

Answer (score 2):

When you use map with dataframe, you need to give encoder.

In spark 2.x `Dataset[Row].map is ((Row) ⇒ T)(Encoder[T]) ⇒ Dataset[T]`

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.RowEncoder
implicit val encoder = RowEncoder(schema)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but appears a new error, check the edit

Comment: I think you should give encoder outside the map over groupedNpa. implicit val encoder = RowEncoder(schema) Give schema of your dataframe.

Comment: same result, how should I pass the map?

Comment: if you could show groupedNpa. I can give try on my shell.

Comment: It's a toy example. The real one I have is far more complex. But, could you add a line in your answer showing how you would invoke the custom function using the encoder?

Comment: show the groupedNpa.. Actually it will give idea. And output what exactly do you want.

Comment: I have asked with a different approach something similar to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46525530/1773841, using a simpler example which may be easier to understand. I would appreciate if you move your answer to that other question so I can close this one, for being almost the same and far worse formulated and harder to understand. I will upvote your answers there as well. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I will look at it when i get time.