# Deduplicate Rows with reduceGroups won't find Encoder[Row]

Tags: scala, apache-spark

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("Test").master("local").getOrCreate()
import spark.implicits._

spark.sparkContext.parallelize(List((50, 2), (34, 4))).toDF("cs_p_id", "cs_ed")
  .groupByKey(_.getAs[String]("cs_p_id"))
  .reduceGroups(Seq(_, _).maxBy(_.getAs[Long]("cs_ed")))
  .map(_._2) // Unable to find encoder for type stored in a Dataset.
```

The above won't compile because the `map` can't find an implicit `Encoder[Row]`.
Surely I'm not the only guy trying to do this simple operation, so what's the way to go?

Thanks

EDIT:
I found this solution that I can't believe people are doing this way:

```
tableData
  .groupByKey(_.getAs[String]("cs_p_id"))
  .reduceGroups(Seq(_, _).maxBy(_.getAs[Long]("cs_ed")))
  .map(_._2)(RowEncoder(tableData.schema))
```

This is not a duplicate of [Encoder error while trying to map dataframe row to updated row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39433419/encoder-error-while-trying-to-map-dataframe-row-to-updated-row) since I'm trying to just remove duplicates.

Comment: There isn't enough code here to reproduce however assuming your local SparkSession instance is bound to variable `spark` then try adding `import spark.implicits._` in the body of your function.

Comment: Thanks @TerryDactyl for your help. This import is already in scope but it doesn't help.

Comment: Can you post a bit more context?

Comment: See edit with a complete example. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Encoder error while trying to map dataframe row to updated row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39433419/encoder-error-while-trying-to-map-dataframe-row-to-updated-row)

Comment: There must be a way to do without going through this row encoder madness