# Spark Dataframe mapPartitions in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

has anyone a working example of the dataframe's mapPartitions function?

Please Note: I'm not looking RDD examples.

**Update:**

The example that has been posted by MasterBuilder if theoretically is ok, but practically has some issue. Please try to get a stream of structured data like a Json

```
val df = spark.load.json("/user/cloudera/json")
val newDF = df.mapPartitions(
  iterator => {

    val result = iterator.map(data=>{/* do some work with data */}).toList
    //return transformed data
    result.iterator
    //now convert back to df
  }

 ).toDF()
```

Ends with this error:

```
<console>:28: error: Unable to find encoder for type stored in a Dataset.  
Primitive types (Int, String, etc) and Product types (case classes) are supported by importing spark.implicits._  
Support for serializing other types will be added in future releases.
```

Is there a way to have this working? 
What's wrong with the above code?

Answer (score 1):

You need an encoder. If your final Dataframe has the same schema as the input Dataframe, then it's just as easy as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.RowEncoder

implicit val encoder = RowEncoder(df.schema)
```

If not, you need to "redefine" the schema and create your encoder.

For more info on the encoder issue, refer to [Encoder error while trying to map dataframe row to updated row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39433419/encoder-error-while-trying-to-map-dataframe-row-to-updated-row) question

Answer (score -3):

```
 import sqlContext.implicits._

    val newDF = df.mapPartitions(
      iterator => {

        val result = iterator.map(data=>{/* do some work with data */}).toList
        //return transformed data
        result.iterator
        //now convert back to df
      }

).toDF()
```

Comment: Hello @Masterbuilder I update the question with more infos.