# org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable. Scala Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Moving an existing application from Spark 1.6 to Spark 2.2* has (eventually) brought about the error “org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable”.  I have oversimplified my code to demonstrate the same error. The code queries a parquet file to return the following datatype: 'org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]' I apply a function to extract a string and integer , returning a string. An inherent issue is related to the point that Spark 2.2 returns a Dataset as opposed to dataframe. (see prior post about the preliminary errors) [How do I write a Dataset encoder to support mapping a function to a org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[String] in Scala Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60865895/how-do-i-write-a-dataset-encoder-to-support-mapping-a-function-to-a-org-apache-s/60903731#60903731)

```
var d1 = hive.executeQuery(st)
d1: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = [cvdt35_message_id_d: string, cvdt35_input_timestamp_s: decimal(16,5) ... 2 more fields]

scala> val parseCVDP_parquet = (s:org.apache.spark.sql.Row) => s.getString(2).split("0x")(1)+","+s.getDecimal(1);
parseCVDP_parquet: org.apache.spark.sql.Row => String = <function1>

scala> var d2 =  d1.map(parseCVDP_parquet)
d2: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[String] = [value: string]

scala> def dd(s:String, start: Int) = { s + "some string" }
dd: (s: String, start: Int)String

scala> var d3 = d2.map{s=> dd(s,5) }
d3: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[String] = [value: string]

scala> d3.take(1)
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
```

My current solution to this problem is through embedding inline code (see below) but is not practical as my production code has substantial parameters and functions that are involved. I have also tried converting to data frame ( as it was in spark 1.6 ) and variations of function definitions which have not proved to represent a workable solution.

```
scala> var d1 = hive.executeQuery(st)
d1: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = [cvdt35_message_id_d: string, cvdt35_input_timestamp_s: decimal(16,5) ... 2 more fields]

scala> val parseCVDP_parquet = (s:org.apache.spark.sql.Row) => s.getString(2).split("0x")(1)+","+s.getDecimal(1);
parseCVDP_parquet: org.apache.spark.sql.Row => String = <function1>

scala> var d2 =  d1.map(parseCVDP_parquet)
d2: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[String] = [value: string]

scala> var d3 = d2.map{s=> { s + "some string" } }
d3: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[String] = [value: string]

scala> d3.take(1)
20/04/30 15:16:17 WARN TaskSetManager: Stage 0 contains a task of very large size (132 KB). The maximum recommended task size is 100 KB.
res1: Array[String] = Array(761f006000705904,1521833533.96682some string)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serialization`

To fix this issue put all your functions & variables inside `Object`. Use those functions & variables wherever it is required.

In this way you can fix most of `serialization` issue

`Example`

```
package common
object AppFunctions {
  def append(s: String, start: Int) = s"${s}some thing"
}

object ExecuteQuery {
 import common.AppFunctions._

 [...]

 val d3 = d2.map(s => append(s,5)) // Pass required values to method.

 [...]


}
```