# Apache Spark 2.0: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No Encoder found for java.time.LocalDate

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset, apache-spark-encoders

I am using Apache Spark 2.0 and creating `case class` for mention schema for `DetaSet`. When i am trying to define custom encoder according to [How to store custom objects in Dataset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36648128/how-to-store-custom-objects-in-a-dataset-in-spark-1-6), for `java.time.LocalDate` i got following exception:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No Encoder found for java.time.LocalDate
- field (class: "java.time.LocalDate", name: "callDate")
- root class: "FireService"
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$ScalaReflection$$serializerFor(ScalaReflection.scala:598)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$9.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:592)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$9.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:583)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:241)
............
```

Following is by code:

```
case class FireService(callNumber: String, callDate: java.time.LocalDate)
implicit val localDateEncoder: org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder[java.time.LocalDate] = org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders.kryo[java.time.LocalDate]

val fireServiceDf = df.map(row => {
val dateFormatter = java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd /yyyy")
FireService(row.getAs[String](0),  java.time.LocalDate.parse(row.getAs[String](4), dateFormatter))
})
```

How we can define third party api's encoder for spark?

**Update**

When i create the encoder for whole case class, `df.map..` map the object into binary, as below:

```
implicit val fireServiceEncoder: org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder[FireService] = org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders.kryo[FireService]

val fireServiceDf = df.map(row => {
 val dateFormatter = java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy")
 FireService(row.getAs[String](0), java.time.LocalDate.parse(row.getAs[String](4), dateFormatter))
})

fireServiceDf: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[FireService] = [value: binary]
```

I am expecting map for FireService, but return binary of map.

Answer (score 5):

As the last comment there says, "if class contains a field Bar you need encoder for a whole object." You need to provide an implicit Encoder for `FireService` itself; otherwise Spark constructs one for you using `SQLImplicits.newProductEncoder[T <: Product : TypeTag]: Encoder[T]`. You can see from the type that it doesn't use any `implicit` Encoder parameters for fields, so it can't use presence of `localDateEncoder`.

Spark could be changed to handle this e.g. using the Shapeless library, or using macros directly; I don't know whether this is the plan in the future.

Comment: Hey @Alexey i got your point still I am not get exact reason, why we required full object formatter?

Comment: i got your point. I also update the question, because now my data is converted into Binary. When i am using Timestamp instead of LocalDate, dataschema build as FireService otherwise as a Binary.

Comment: Please ask that as a separate question. In general, don't edit a question to ask a different one.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov I'm facing the same issue. Do you have a code example of how to encode the whole project? Many Thanks!