# How to build right StructType for Spark schema with array of several type of objects?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

The structure what I have:

```
{
 "person":"Jhon",
 [
    {"model":"golf","mark":"vw","fuel":"d","year":2000},
    {"model":"yamaha r1","year":1998,"abs":true}
 ]
}
//
StructType(
  StructField("person", StringPrimitive, false),
  ArrayType( /* ???? */ ) // Should be possible to define several structures
)
```

So, the Idea is simple. Some person has array of his own transport and this transport can be of type: CarEntity, MotorcycleEntity, BicycleEntity, AirplaneEntity and so on...

The second situation when I receive only one transport entity for each person. Smth like this:

```
{"person":"Jhon",{"model":"yamaha r1","year":1998,"abs":true}}
//
StructType(
  StructField("person", StringPrimitive, false),
  StructField( /* ???? */ ) // Should be possible to define several structures
)
```

And in this case the transport can be one of previously mentioned types.

What is the right way to build StructType for that?

How to define `ArrayType` of multiple types or multiple `StructType` types?

Comment: is this the valid json

Comment: @SomeshwarKale, it is example but I've made changes to better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spark 1.x you could try to achieve the same result with an UDT (as described in this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39096268/how-to-use-user-defined-types-in-spark-2-0)). But for Spark 2.x this functionality has been removed.

Comment: I have Spark 2.4 and as I see in spark-catalyst_2.11:2.4.6 the `UserDefinedType` is present.

Comment: @RudyVeroven do you know how to do it with UDT?