# Building decision tree pipeline for kyro-encoded Datasets in spark 2.0.2 with Java

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I'm trying to build a version of the decision tree classification example from Spark 2.0.2 org.apache.spark.examples.ml.JavaDecisionTreeClassificationExample. I can't use this directly because it uses libsvm-encoded data. I need to avoid libsvm (undocumented AFAIK) to classify ordinary datasets more easily. I'm trying to adapt the example to use a kyro-encoded dataset instead.

The issue originates in the map call below, particularly the consequences of using Encoders.kyro as the encoder as instructed by [SparkML feature vectors and Spark 2.0.2 Encoders in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41266501/sparkml-feature-vectors-and-spark-2-0-2-encoders-in-java/41269035?noredirect=1#comment69752539_41269035)

```
    public SMLDecisionTree(Dataset<Row> incomingDS, final String label, final String[] features)
{
    this.incomingDS = incomingDS;
    this.label = label;
    this.features = features;
    this.mapSet = new StringToDoubleMapperSet(features);

    this.sdlDS = incomingDS
            .select(label, features)
            .filter(new FilterFunction<Row>()
            {
                public boolean call(Row row) throws Exception
                {
                    return !row.getString(0).equals(features[0]); // header
                }
            })
            .map(new MapFunction<Row, LabeledFeatureVector>()
            {
                public LabeledFeatureVector call(Row row) throws Exception
                {
                    double labelVal = mapSet.addValue(0, row.getString(0));
                    double[] featureVals = new double[features.length];
                    for (int i = 1; i < row.length(); i++)
                    {
                        Double val = mapSet.addValue(i, row.getString(i));
                        featureVals[i - 1] = val;
                    }
                    return new LabeledFeatureVector(labelVal, Vectors.dense(featureVals));
                }
                // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36648128/how-to-store-custom-objects-in-a-dataset
            }, Encoders.kryo(LabeledFeatureVector.class));

    Dataset<LabeledFeatureVector>[] splits = sdlDS.randomSplit(new double[] { 0.7, 0.3 });
    this.trainingDS = splits[0];
    this.testDS = splits[1];
}
```

This impacts the StringIndexer and VectorIndexer from the original spark example which are unable to handle the resulting kyro-encoded dataset. Here is the pipeline building code taken from the spark decision tree example code:

```
public void run() throws IOException
{
    sdlDS.show();
    StringIndexerModel labelIndexer = new StringIndexer()
            .setInputCol("label")
            .setOutputCol("indexedLabel")
            .fit(df);

    VectorIndexerModel featureIndexer = new VectorIndexer()
            .setInputCol("features")
            .setOutputCol("indexedFeatures")
            .setMaxCategories(4) // treat features with > 4 distinct values as continuous.
            .fit(df);

    DecisionTreeClassifier classifier = new DecisionTreeClassifier()
            .setLabelCol("indexedLabel")
            .setFeaturesCol("indexedFeatures");

    IndexToString labelConverter = new IndexToString()
            .setInputCol("prediction")
            .setOutputCol("predictedLabel")
            .setLabels(labelIndexer.labels());

    Pipeline pipeline = new Pipeline().setStages(new PipelineStage[]
    { labelIndexer, featureIndexer, classifier, labelConverter });
```

This code apparently expects a dataset with "label" and "features" columns with the label and a Vector of double-encoded features. The problem is that kyro produces a single column named "values" that seems to hold a byte array. I know of no documentation for how to convert this to what the original StringIndexer and VectorIndexer expect. Can someone help? Java please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use Kryo encoder in the first place. It is very limited in general and not applicable here at all. The simplest solution here is to drop custom class and use `Row` encoder. First you'll need a bunch of imports:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.RowEncoder;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataTypes;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType;
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.*;
```

and a schema:

```
List<StructField> fields = new ArrayList<>();

fields.add(DataTypes.createStructField("label", DoubleType, false));
fields.add(DataTypes.createStructField("features", new VectorUDT(), false));
StructType schema = DataTypes.createStructType(fields);
```

Encoder can be defined like this:

```
Encoder<Row> encoder = RowEncoder.apply(schema);
```

and use as shown below:

```
Dataset<Row> inputDs = spark.read().json(sc.parallelize(Arrays.asList(
        "{\"lablel\": 1.0, \"features\": \"foo\"}"
)));

inputDs.map(new MapFunction<Row, Row>() {
    public Row call(Row row) {
        return RowFactory.create(1.0, Vectors.dense(1.0, 2.0));
    }
}, encoder);
```