# why does DataFrame Row.getAs[Vector] fail?

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark DataFrame with two columns of types String and org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.SparseVector and this works fine:

```
data.map(r => r(1).asInstanceOf[Vector])
```

But getAs

```
data.map(r => r.getAs[Vector](1))
```

fails with

> error: Unable to find encoder for type stored in a Dataset.  Primitive
>   types (Int, String, etc) and Product types (case classes) are
>   supported by importing spark.implicits._  Support for serializing
>   other types will be added in future releases.

Please can you explain why?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

`data.rdd.map(r => r.getAs[Vector](1))`

for more information about `Encoder` and `Dataset`  you can read [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36648128/how-to-store-custom-objects-in-dataset)