# spark create dataset from typed sequence

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Similar to the spark documentation here:

> http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html
>
> ```
> case class Person(name: String, age: Long)
> val caseClassDS = Seq(Person("Andy", 32)).toDS()
> caseClassDS.show()
> ```

error for a sequence of `Seq[org.opengis.feature.simple.SimpleFeature]`:

```
/geomesaSparkFirstSteps/src/main/scala/myOrg/GeoInMemory.scala:162: value toDS is not a member of Seq[org.opengis.feature.simple.SimpleFeature]
[error]   geoResult.toDS()
```

see https://github.com/geoHeil/geomesaSparkFirstSteps/blob/master/src/main/scala/myOrg/GeoInMemory.scala#L162 for details

How can I fix this statement? Is the encoder from `Seq[someObject]` issing?

Comment: @Downvoter please explain why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conversions between `Seq` and `Dataset` [require an `implicit` `Encoder`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$implicits$@localSeqToDatasetHolder[T](s:Seq[T])(implicitevidence$5:org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder[T]):org.apache.spark.sql.DatasetHolder[T]) for the stored class.

```
implicit def localSeqToDatasetHolder[T](s: Seq[T])(
  implicit arg0: Encoder[T]): DatasetHolder[T]
```

Product types (like cases classes) containing common Scala types use implicit `Encoders` provided by `SparkSession.implicits`. For arbitrary class you'll have to use generic Java or Kryo encoder. See [How to store custom objects in Dataset?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36648128/6910411) for details.