# Spark DataFrame to DataSet with custom columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark, casting, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

We are struggling to convert a Spark DataFrame to a DataSet of case class with dynamic columns. Starting points for each use case are DataFrames like the one below:

```
root
|-- id: string (nullable = true)
|-- time: long (nullable = true)
|-- c: struct (nullable = true)
|    |-- d: long (nullable = true)
|    |-- e: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- f: array (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
|    |    |    |-- g: long (nullable = true)
|-- x: string (nullable = true)
|-- y: string (nullable = true)
```

All these DataFrames have `id` and `time` column in common. The other columns (`c`, `x`, `y`) are configurable and can be vary for each use case in count (in some DataFrames we have up to 10 columns beside `id` and `time`) and type.

To simplify the complex processing of the these events we would like to cast each row to a scala case class like this:

```
case class Event(id: String, time: Long, payload: Seq[Any])
```

or:

```
case class Event(id: String, time: Long, payload: Map[String, Any]) // payload: <column-name>/<value>
```

Sadly, `df.as[Event]` doesn't work out of the box. Any ideas, how to do the trick?

Writing a case class for every use case is not an option, because we just want to configure the job via a YAML file and don't want to adjust the code for every new use case. We need something more generic! (I thought about generating a case class at runtime, but this is quite complicated...)

Thanks for your help!

**Update - Solution**

We now came up with the following solution:

case class Event(id: String, time: Long, payload: Seq[Array[Byte]])

and convert the DataFrame with the help of `kryo`:

```
val idIndex = df.columns.indexOf("id")
val timeIndex = df.columns.indexOf("time")
val otherColumns = List.range(0, df.columns.length).filterNot(i => i == idIndex && i == timeIndex)

val kryo = new Kryo()

val ds = df.map(row => {
  Event(
    row.getAs[String](idIndex),
    row.getAs[Long](timeIndex),
    otherColumns.map(index => {
      val output = new Output(192, 8192)
      kryo.writeObject(output, row.get(index))
      output.getBuffer
    })
  )
})

ds.printSchema()
```

Thx, for your help.

Comment: A `Dataset` can't be created for a structure that contains `Any`, since `Any` doesn't have an Encoder (Spark has built-in encoders for all primitive types and Product types that store them efficiently in memory - but `Any` could be anything and therefore can't be Encoded), and whatever encoder you do create for it would probably make it useless... see more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36648128/how-to-store-custom-objects-in-a-dataset