# spark implicit encoder not found in scope

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, implicit-conversion, apache-spark-encoders

I have a problem with spark already outlined in [spark custom kryo encoder not providing schema for UDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44735235/spark-custom-kryo-encoder-not-providing-schema-for-udf) but created a minimal sample now: 
https://gist.github.com/geoHeil/dc9cfb8eca5c06fca01fc9fc03431b2f

```
class SomeOtherClass(foo: Int)
case class FooWithSomeOtherClass(a: Int, b: String, bar: SomeOtherClass)
case class FooWithoutOtherClass(a: Int, b: String, bar: Int)
case class Foo(a: Int)
implicit val someOtherClassEncoder: Encoder[SomeOtherClass] = Encoders.kryo[SomeOtherClass]
val df2 = Seq(FooWithSomeOtherClass(1, "one", new SomeOtherClass(4))).toDS
val df3 = Seq(FooWithoutOtherClass(1, "one", 1), FooWithoutOtherClass(2, "two", 2)).toDS
val df4 = df3.map(d => FooWithSomeOtherClass(d.a, d.b, new SomeOtherClass(d.bar)))
```

here, even the `createDataSet` statement fails due to

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No Encoder found for SomeOtherClass
- field (class: "SomeOtherClass", name: "bar")
- root class: "FooWithSomeOtherClass"
```

Why is the encoder not in scope or at least not in the right scope?

Also, trying to specify an explicit encoder like:

```
df3.map(d => {FooWithSomeOtherClass(d.a, d.b, new SomeOtherClass(d.bar))}, (Int, String, Encoders.kryo[SomeOtherClass]))
```

does not work.

Comment: If you want more than just a binary blob, take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36648128/3072788).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because you should use the Kryo encoder through the whole serialization stack, meaning that your top-level object should have a Kryo encoder. The following runs successfully on a local Spark shell (the change you are interested in is on the first line):

```
  implicit val topLevelObjectEncoder: Encoder[FooWithSomeOtherClass] = Encoders.kryo[FooWithSomeOtherClass]

  val df1 = Seq(Foo(1), Foo(2)).toDF

  val df2 = Seq(FooWithSomeOtherClass(1, "one", new SomeOtherClass(4))).toDS

  val df3 = Seq(FooWithoutOtherClass(1, "one", 1), FooWithoutOtherClass(2, "two", 2)).toDS
  df3.printSchema
  df3.show

  val df4 = df3.map(d => FooWithSomeOtherClass(d.a, d.b, new SomeOtherClass(d.bar)))
  df4.printSchema
  df4.show
  df4.collect
```

Comment: I see. But this transforms the whole schema to a single binary column. I would rather have multiple (original column) where a single one is serialized via kayo/binary. Is this possible as well? I have seen some java projects explicitly serializing like `Encoders.tuple(Encoders.STRING(), Encoders.kryo(Mything.class)))` which seems to provide the desired behaviour. However, I do not yet know how to reproduce this in the Scala api.

Comment: I guess that you are unable to make this a `case class`, either directly or by copying it's information, right?

Comment: It would be possible at least for parts of the desired functionality. However, when looking at it regarding usability, it would be great if I could dimply apply kryo to the one single filed which itself is not a product.