# Dataset encoder for scala collections

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset, apache-spark-encoders

I get exception when trying to read dataset from s3. Company case class contains set with Employee case classe.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No Encoder found for Set[com.model.company.common.Employee]
- field (class: "scala.collection.immutable.Set", name: "employees")
- field (class: "com.model.company.Company", name: "company")
```

I tried with kryo:

> ```
> implicit def myDataEncoder[T]: Encoder[Set[Employee]] = Encoders.kryo[scala.collection.immutable.Set[Employee]
> ```

but it also doesn't work.
Do you know how to convert scala collection to dataset ?

Code:

> ```
> val sqlContext = sparkSession.sqlContext
> import sqlContext.implicits._
>
> val records = sparkSession.read.json(s"s3a://${config.input.fullPath}").as[Company]
> ```

Comment: can you add the code you have tried?

Comment: Is the implicit in scope?

Comment: see my code above

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45020230/apache-spark-2-1-java-lang-unsupportedoperationexception-no-encoder-found-for

Answer (score 0):

Change from List,Set -> Seq

More information about dataset data type you can find here:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#data-types