# How to use java.time.LocalDate in Datasets (fails with java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No Encoder found)?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

- Spark 2.1.1
- Scala 2.11.8
- Java 8
- Linux Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

I'd like to transform my RDD into a Dataset. For this, I use the `implicits` method `toDS()` that give me the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No Encoder found for java.time.LocalDate
- field (class: "java.time.LocalDate", name: "date")
- root class: "observatory.TemperatureRow"
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$ScalaReflection$$serializerFor(ScalaReflection.scala:602)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$9.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:596)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$9.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:587)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.flatMap(List.scala:344)
```

In my case, I must use the type `java.time.LocalDate`, I can't use the `java.sql.data`. I have read that I need to informe Spark how transforme Java type into Sql type, I this direction, I build the 2 implicits functions below:

```
implicit def toSerialized(t: TemperatureRow): EncodedTemperatureRow = EncodedTemperatureRow(t.date.toString, t.location, t.temperature)
implicit def fromSerialized(t: EncodedTemperatureRow): TemperatureRow = TemperatureRow(LocalDate.parse(t.date), t.location, t.temperature)
```

---

Below, some code about my application:

```
case class Location(lat: Double, lon: Double)

case class TemperatureRow(
                             date: LocalDate,
                             location: Location,
                             temperature: Double
                         )

case class EncodedTemperatureRow(
                             date: String,
                             location: Location,
                             temperature: Double

val s = Seq[TemperatureRow](
                    TemperatureRow(LocalDate.parse("2017-01-01"), Location(1.4,5.1), 4.9),
                    TemperatureRow(LocalDate.parse("2014-04-05"), Location(1.5,2.5), 5.5)
                )

import spark.implicits._
val temps: RDD[TemperatureRow] = sc.parallelize(s)
val tempsDS = temps.toDS
```

I don't know why Spark search an encoder for `java.time.LocalDate`, I provide implicit conversions for `TemperatureRow` and `EncodedTemperatureRow`...

Comment: The implicit conversions you've supplied are simply useless for Spark - how would the framework "know" to convert objects into `EncodedTemperatureRow`? Spark requires implicit values with type `org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder[T]` to encode values of type `T`, so you'd need to supply an impllicit `Encoder[TemperatureRow]`. Creating such encoders is not trivial, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/39442829/5344058

Answer (score 16):

`java.time.LocalDate` is not supported up to Spark 2.2 (and I've been trying to write an `Encoder` for the type for some time and [failed](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-ExpressionEncoder-LocalDateTime.html)).

You have to convert `java.time.LocalDate` to some other supported type (e.g. `java.sql.Timestamp` or `java.sql.Date`), or epoch or date-time in string.

Comment: And to clarify for anyone landing here: not even version 2.2 of Spark handles the JDK8 date/time classes. The conversion in https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/literals.scala only look at the pre-JDK8 date/time classes.

Comment: so how do you do that? i.e. code plz

Comment: You simply `map` or `withColumn` to some other type to avoid this issue.

Comment: It seems like Spark 3 will support it. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-27222 and https://github.com/apache/spark/commit/0f4f8160e6d01d2e263adcf39d53bd0a03fc1b73#diff-f52e4a77ff9291d86359d609a9757781

Comment: Any comments on why [it](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/content/spark-sql-ExpressionEncoder-LocalDateTime.html) failed?