# Does Apache spark 2.2 supports user-defined type (UDT)?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

From this JIRA ticket [Hide UserDefinedType in Spark 2.0](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-14155)
, seems that spark hide the UDT API from version 2.0.

Is there exists an alternative function or API we can use in version 2.2,  so that we could define UserDefinedType? I wish to use a custom type in dataframe or structured streaming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no alternative API and UDT remains private (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-7768).

Generic `Encoders` (`org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders.kryo` and `org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders.javaSerialization`) serve similar purpose in `Dataset`, but there are not direct replacement:

- [How to store custom objects in Dataset?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36648128/8371915)
- [Questions about the future of UDTs and Encoders](http://apache-spark-developers-list.1001551.n3.nabble.com/Questions-about-the-future-of-UDTs-and-Encoders-td22153.html)