# Spark DataFrame not supporting Char datatype

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am creating a Spark DataFrame from a text file. Say Employee file which contains String, Int, Char.

created a class:

```
case class Emp (
  Name: String, 
  eid: Int, 
  Age: Int, 
  Sex: Char, 
  Sal: Int, 
  City: String)
```

Created RDD1 using split, then created RDD2:

```
val textFileRDD2 = textFileRDD1.map(attributes => Emp(
  attributes(0), 
  attributes(1).toInt, 
  attributes(2).toInt, 
  attributes(3).charAt(0), 
  attributes(4).toInt, 
  attributes(5)))
```

And Final RDDS as:

```
finalRDD = textFileRDD2.toDF
```

when I create final RDD it throws the error:

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No Encoder found for scala.Char"

can anyone help me out why and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spark SQL doesn't provide `Encoders` for `Char` and [generic `Encoders` are not very useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36648128/how-to-store-custom-objects-in-dataset).

You can either use a `StringType`:

```
attributes(3).slice(0, 1)
```

or `ShortType` (or `BooleanType`, `ByteType` if you accept only binary response):

```
attributes(3)(0) match {
   case 'F' => 1: Short
   ...
   case _ => 0: Short
}
```