# Spark: Dataset Serialization

Tags: scala, apache-spark, serialization, apache-spark-dataset

If I have a dataset each record of which is a case class, and I persist that dataset as shown below so that serialization is used:

```
myDS.persist(StorageLevel.MERORY_ONLY_SER)
```

Does Spark use java/kyro serialization to serialize the dataset? or just like dataframe, Spark has its own way of storing the data in the dataset?

Answer (score 12):

Spark `Dataset` does not use standard serializers. Instead it uses `Encoders`, which "understand" internal structure of the data and can efficiently transform objects (anything that have `Encoder`, including `Row`) into internal binary storage.

The only case where Kryo or Java serialization is used, is when you [explicitly apply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36648128/how-to-store-custom-objects-in-dataset) `Encoders.kryo[_]` or `Encoders.java[_]`. In any other case Spark will destructure the object representation and try to apply standard encoders (atomic encoders, `Product` encoder, etc.). The only difference compared to `Row` is its `Encoder` - `RowEncoder` (in a sense `Encoders` are similar to lenses).

Databricks explicitly puts `Encoder` / `Dataset` serialization in contrast to Java and Kryo serializers, in its [Introducing Apache Spark Datasets](https://databricks.com/blog/2016/01/04/introducing-apache-spark-datasets.htm) (look especially for  *Lightning-fast Serialization with Encoders* section)

[image]

[image]

Source of the images

- Michael Armbrust, Wenchen Fan, Reynold Xin and Matei Zaharia. Introducing Apache Spark Datasets, https://databricks.com/blog/2016/01/04/introducing-apache-spark-datasets.html

Comment: this is exactly correct and it's always almost recommend to use Kyro serde lib. since it's much faster than Java serde and perf improvement is a lot. it also seamlessly integrate with Java serde framework. so java.io.Serializable is the only thing needed from Kyro to serialize your custom data structures. to see concrete example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53329178/spark-no-encoder-found-for-java-io-serializable-in-mapstring-java-io-serializa/53356578#53356578

Answer (score 3):

`Dataset[SomeCaseClass]` is not different from `Dataset[Row]` or any other `Dataset`. It uses the same internal representation (mapped to instances of external class *when needed*) and the same serialization method.

Therefore, the is no need for direct object serialization (Java, Kryo).

Comment: In recent versions of Spark, we mainly have DataSet and Dataframe, with  Dataframe being just a special case of Dataset.  So, if serialization has no effect on Datasets, then why do Spark developers push for Kyro?  So, I'm not sure what you say above is  accurate.  I think if Dataframe records are objects, then these objects are serialized. So, the Dataset itself might not use serialization, but the objects are serialized.

Answer (score -2):

Under the hood, a dataset is an RDD.  From the [documentation for RDD persistence](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/rdd-programming-guide.html#rdd-persistence):

> Store RDD as serialized Java objects (one byte array per partition). This is generally more space-efficient than deserialized objects, especially when using a fast serializer, but more CPU-intensive to read.

By default, Java serialization is used [source](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/rdd-programming-guide.html#rdd-persistence):

> By default, Spark serializes objects using Java’s ObjectOutputStream framework... Spark can also use the Kryo library (version 2) to serialize objects more quickly.

To enable Kryo, initialize the job with a SparkConf and set `spark.serializer` to `org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer`:

```
val conf = new SparkConf()
             .set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
```

You may need to register classes with Kryo before creating the SparkContext:

```
conf.registerKryoClasses(Array(classOf[Class1], classOf[Class2]))
```