# Spark: can I convert a Scala set to a DataType in spark SQL?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-2.0

For example, Scala array corresponds to ArrayType in Spark SQL, which can be used in schema definitions. For Map there's MapType.

How about **Set**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A set (no pun intended) of supported types is limited a not extensible. You'll find a full list of supported types in the [Spark SQL, DataFrames and Datasets Guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html) - as you can check there is no type for `Set`.

The best you can do is to use `ArrayType` which maps to `scala.collection.Seq` and handle set specific operations yourself.

It is possible to use binary `Encoders` ([How to store custom objects in Dataset?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36648128/8371915)) but these are intended for strongly typed datasets, and have limited applications when used with `DataFrames`.

Answer (score 0):

There is none. Exhaustive list is here: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#data-types

Find full example code at "`examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/sql/SparkSQLExample.scala`" in the Spark repo.