# How to make an Encoder for scala Iterable, spark dataset

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset, apache-spark-encoders

I'm trying to create a Dataset from a RDD `y`

`Pattern: y: RDD[(MyObj1, scala.Iterable[MyObj2])]`

So I created explicitly *encoder*  :

```
implicit def tuple2[A1, A2](
                              implicit e1: Encoder[A1],
                              e2: Encoder[A2]
                            ): Encoder[(A1,A2)] = Encoders.tuple[A1,A2](e1, e2) 
//Create Dataset
val z = spark.createDataset(y)(tuple2[MyObj1, Iterable[MyObj2]])
```

When I compile this code I don't have an Error but when I try to run it I get this Error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No Encoder found for scala.Iterable[org.bean.input.MyObj2]
- field (class: "scala.collection.Iterable", name: "_2")
- root class: "scala.Tuple2"
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$ScalaReflection$$serializerFor(ScalaReflection.scala:625)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$10.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:619)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$10.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:607)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:241)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.flatMap(List.scala:344)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$ScalaReflection$$serializerFor(ScalaReflection.scala:607)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.serializerFor(ScalaReflection.scala:438)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder$.apply(ExpressionEncoder.scala:71)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders$.product(Encoders.scala:275)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.LowPrioritySQLImplicits$class.newProductEncoder(SQLImplicits.scala:233)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLImplicits.newProductEncoder(SQLImplicits.scala:33)
```

Some explanation for my objects (MyObj1 & MyObj2)
**- MyObj1 :**

```
case class MyObj1(
                      id:String,
                      type:String
                  )
```

**- MyObj2 :**

```
trait MyObj2 {
  val o_state:Option[String]

  val n_state:Option[String]

  val ch_inf: MyObj1

  val state_updated:MyObj3
}
```

Any Help please

Comment: Have you imported `spark.implicits._` (where `spark` is the name of your `SparkSession`)? I think that will give you access to an encoder for tuples as well. You may also need to supply encoders for `MyObj` and `MyObj2`.

Comment: @hoyland Probably did, otherwise it would be complication error I guess.

Comment: yes I imported `spark.implicits._

Answer (score 2):

Spark doesn't provide `Encoder` for `Iterables`, so unless you want to use `Encoder.kryo` or `Encoder.java` this won't work.

The closest subclass of `Iterable` for which Spark provides `Encoders` is `Seq`, so this is probably the one you should use here. Otherwise refer to [How to store custom objects in Dataset?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36648128/8371915)

Comment: yes I tried the kryo encoder : `implicit  def chargingStatEncoder [A] (implicit cs: ClassTag [A]) = org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders.kryo[A](cs)`. But My dataset is : `Pattern: z: Dataset[(MyObj1, scala.Iterable[MyObj2])]`. How can I implement it ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to change declaration to: `val y: RDD[(MyObj1, Seq[MyObj2])]` and it would work. I checked it for my classes:

```
case class Key(key: String) {}
case class Value(value: Int) {}
```

For:

```
val y: RDD[(Key, Seq[Value])] = sc.parallelize(Map(
  Key("A") -> List(Value(1), Value(2)),
  Key("B") -> List(Value(3), Value(4), Value(5))
).toSeq)

val z = sparkSession.createDataset(y)
z.show()
```

I got:

```
+---+---------------+
| _1|             _2|
+---+---------------+
|[A]|     [[1], [2]]|
|[B]|[[3], [4], [5]]|
+---+---------------+
```

If I change to `Iterable` I got exception you got.

Comment: When I work with seq I get another error because I have **another Objects** in MyObj2 *MyObj1 & MyObj3*