# Storing simple map in Spark Dataframe field

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have some JSON Data which I'd like to store in parsed form (meaning a Map[String,Any]) within a Spark Dataframe.

Is there any way to do this?  I think it involves an Encoder, but I'm not sure where to start.

Answer (score 0):

Not in an useful way. You can use strongly typed `Dataset` with Kryo encoder

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Encoder, Encoders}

implicit val mapStrAnyEnc: Encoder[Map[String, Any]] = Encoders.kryo
Seq(Map("foo" -> 1.0, "bar" -> "foo")).toDS.show

// +--------------------+
// |               value|
// +--------------------+
// |[35 01 02 40 01 0...|
// +--------------------+
```

but value of representation like this is close to none if you want to use `DataFrames`.

A natural mapping for heterogeneous object is `struct`, but if number of fields is large or unbounded, your best options is to go with `Map[String, String]` and parse values only when needed.

Comment: Actually I'd like to have the value field be a payload which I can process on the scala side:  So it's more like
`Seq((1, Map("foo" -> 1.0, "bar" -> "foo"))).toDS.show`

Comment: It is not an issue (see https://stackoverflow.com/q/36648128/8371915) but usability is still rather low. And it of course add on top of handling `Anys`, which is a mess alone.

Comment: Huh, and is there any way to encode a `case class Foo(id: Int, map Map[String,Any])` class?  I really just want to look up a record by id and then look at the map in client code.