# In Java, how to convert scala.list to java.list

Tags: java, scala, scala-java-interop

In Java, I already have a `scala.collection.mutable.wrappedArray` object. How can I convert it to `util.ArrayList` or `util.linkedList` in Java? Or alternatively, How can I iterate it and do something with each value of it? `foreach` is not applicable.

Comment: You want to iterate over it but you can't use a for-each loop? Why is that? For-each is the most straightforward, not to mention general, iteration tool at your disposal.

Answer (score 4):

I don't want to claim that it's "impossible" to use a `scala.collection.mutable.wrappedArray` from your Java code, but in my opinion, if you are asking such questions, you're doing it wrong.

Scala's standard library **does** provide a lot of functionality to convert between Scala data structures and Java data structures.

Java standard library **does not** provide any tools to deal with Scala collections, it does not know anything at all about Scala.

Therefore, the question *"how can I convert `scala.x.y.Z` to `java.r.s.T` **in Java**"* is essentially meaningless: don't try to perform the conversion in Java, do it in Scala, it's much easier.

---

**General approach**

Suppose that you have a method `foo` implemented in Scala that returns a Scala-specific data structure `scala.x.y.Z`:

```
// Scala code
def foo(): scala.x.y.Z = ???
```

Apparently, what you are trying to do is:

```
// Java code
scala.x.y.Z a = yourScalaLibrary.foo();
java.r.s.T b = /* 
  crazily complex java code
  that converts scaa.x.y.Z to java.r.s.T
*/
```

My suggestion is: just don't do it. Instead, implement an additional Java-specific API *in Scala*:

```
// Scala code
def javaFoo(): java.r.s.T = {
  scala.x.y.Z a = foo()
  java.r.s.T b = /* simple conversion code using Scala-Java interop */
  b  // return Java-specific collection
}
```

And then use only the Java-API in your Java code:

```
// Java code
java.r.s.T b = javaFoo();
```

---

**Concrete example**

Assuming that you want to use this method from Java:

```
def foo(): scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3)
```

you first implement a java-API (in Scala!):

```
import collection.JavaConverters._
def javaFoo(): java.util.List[Int] = foo().asJava
```

and then use it from Java:

```
java.util.List myList = javaFoo();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tried to do that in Scala and it works! But one more question: 

Could you please tell me how to save a Scala `DataFrame` object with `parquet` format with each row contains a, say, `java.util.ArrayList` object? Or any object the class of which implements `List` interface? Directly save it will leading to the following error:

`
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No Encoder found for java.util.ArrayList[Double]
`

Comment: @YimingSun This looks like it should be a separate question tagged `[apache-spark]` and `[parquet]`. Maybe you can find some useful hints [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36648128/how-to-store-custom-objects-in-dataset), but I cannot guarantee that there weren't any changes in the most recent versions.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I ended up doing (in Java):

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters;
/* ... */
JavaConverters.mutableSeqAsJavaList(yourArray.seq());
```

As far as I know, `scala.*` packages naturally get into classpath once you have any library that uses Scala (and specifically the one you want to convert the data from).

Answer (score 0):

That's an old answer. The right way to use it is as shown below

```
import scala.jdk.CollectionConverters.*
val javaList: java.util.List[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3).toList.asJava
```