# Handling models with circular references in Spark SQL?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

Yesterday (practically the full journal) I tried to figure out an elegant way to represent a model with circular references in **Scala/Spark SQL 2.2.1**

Let's say that this is the original model approach that, of course, it is not working (keep in mind that the real model has tens of attributes):

```
case class Branch(id: Int, branches: List[Branch] = List.empty)
case class Tree(id: Int, branches: List[Branch])

val trees = Seq(Tree(1, List(Branch(2, List.empty), Branch(3, List(Branch(4, List.empty))))))

val ds = spark.createDataset(trees)
ds.show
```

And this is the error that it throws:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: cannot have circular references in class, but got the circular reference of class Branch
```

I know that the **maximum hierarchy level that we have is 5**. So, as a workaround, I though in something like:

```
case class BranchLevel5(id: Int)
case class BranchLevel4(id: Int, branches: List[BranchLevel5] = List.empty)
case class BranchLevel3(id: Int, branches: List[BranchLevel4] = List.empty)
case class BranchLevel2(id: Int, branches: List[BranchLevel3] = List.empty)
case class BranchLevel1(id: Int, branches: List[BranchLevel2] = List.empty)
case class Tree(id: Int, branches: List[BranchLevel1])
```

Of course, it is working. But this is not elegant at all and you can imagine the pain around the implementation (readability, coupling, maintenance, usability, duplication of code, etc.)

So the question is, *how to handle cases with circular references in the model?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're fine with using private API, then I found one way that just works: treating the whole self-referential structure as a user-defined type. I'm following the approach from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51957666/1823254.

```
package org.apache.spark.custom.udts // we're calling some private API so need to be under 'org.apache.spark'

import java.io._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{DataType, UDTRegistration, UserDefinedType}

class BranchUDT extends UserDefinedType[Branch] {

  override def sqlType: DataType = org.apache.spark.sql.types.BinaryType
  override def serialize(obj: Branch): Any = {
    val bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    val oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos)
    oos.writeObject(obj)
    bos.toByteArray
  }
  override def deserialize(datum: Any): Branch = {
    val bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(datum.asInstanceOf[Array[Byte]])
    val ois = new ObjectInputStream(bis)
    val obj = ois.readObject()
    obj.asInstanceOf[Branch]
  }

  override def userClass: Class[Branch] = classOf[Branch]
}

object BranchUDT {
  def register() = UDTRegistration.register(classOf[Branch].getName, classOf[BranchUDT].getName)
}
```

Just create and register a custom UDT, and that's it!

```
BranchUDT.register()
val trees = Seq(Tree(1, List(Branch(2, List.empty), Branch(3, List(Branch(4, List.empty))))))

val ds = spark.createDataset(trees)
ds.show(false)

//+---+----------------------------------------------------+
//|id |branches                                            |
//+---+----------------------------------------------------+
//|1  |[Branch(2,List()), Branch(3,List(Branch(4,List())))]|
//+---+----------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Good point but I don't like the idea to use hidden private stuff that easily is going to change in new versions. IMO, If it is private, pretty sure that it is because of a reason.

Comment: I can not do your code work. Where do you put this line? UDTRegistration.register(classOf[Branch].getName, classOf[BranchUDT].getName)

Comment: @angelcervera It's the part that access the private API, therefore need to be in a file under package org.apache.spark. I'll update the post.

Comment: I tried that before and did not work. I did something wrong. The important is that your code works like a charm (except the kryo import that for me is com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo) Thanks!

Comment: The big limitation of the solution is that is not possible to access the fields of the custom type from spark sql or use the built-in funtions. :(

Comment: BTW, why do you need to create an instance of Kryo if you never use it?

Comment: You're right on the limitation - once we treat it as a custom type then all column-based operations would no longer work. That's probably why circular types are forbidden in the first place.

Comment: and yes the Kryo instance is unnecessary - thanks for the catch!