# Encode ujson.Value in Spark Dataset

Tags: scala, apache-spark, upickle

Let's say I have these JSON lines stored is a text file.

```
{"a": "...", "data": [{}]}
{"a": "...", "data": [{"b": "..."}]}
{"a": "...", "data": [{"d": "..."}]}
{"a": "...", "data": [{"b": "...", "c": "..."}]}
```

I would like to process the file to a Spark `Dataset`, but I don't know the precise schema of the field `data`. I used `upickle` to convert the JSON to a case class

```
case class MyCC(a: String, data: Seq[ujson.Value.Obj])

implicit val r: Reader[MyCC] = macroR

sc.textFile("s3://path/to/file.txt")
  .map(uread[MyCC](_))
  .toDS                 // Dataset[MyCC]
  .show()
```

Trying this, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No Encoder found for ujson.Value
- map value class: "ujson.Value"
- field (class: "scala.collection.mutable.LinkedHashMap", name: 
"value")
- array element class: "ujson.Obj"
- field (class: "scala.collection.Seq", name: "data")
- root class: "com.mycaule.MyCC"
```

How do I solve this data modelization problem ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I could read the data in without creating the custom encoders as required. I just defined the case class properly.

```
import scala.collection.mutable
case class CustomClass( a: String,
                        data: List[mutable.HashMap[String,String]]
                              )

val dataSourceName =  "s3/path/to/data.json"

val schema = ScalaReflection.schemaFor[CustomClass].dataType.asInstanceOf[StructType]

val data = spark.read.schema(schema).json(dataSourceName).as[CustomClass]

data.show(10, truncate = false)
```

Following is the output :

```
+---+----------------------+
|a  |data                  |
+---+----------------------+
|...|[[]]                  |
|...|[[b -> ...]]          |
|...|[[d -> ...]]          |
|...|[[b -> ..., c -> ...]]|
+---+----------------------+
```

Comment: What if `{"a": "...", "data": [{"b": []}]}`

Comment: @MichelHua : You might benefit from this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36648128/how-to-store-custom-objects-in-dataset/39442829#39442829