# Spark using recursive case class

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I have a Datastructure that is recursive. Spark gives this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: cannot have circular references in class, but got the circular reference of class BulletPoint
```

As an example I did this code:

```
case class BulletPoint(item: String, children: List[BulletPoint])

object TestApp extends App {
  val sparkSession = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .appName("spark app")
    .master(s"local")
    .getOrCreate()

  import sparkSession.implicits._

  sparkSession.createDataset(List(BulletPoint("1", Nil), BulletPoint("2", Nil)))
}
```

Does someone have an idea how one can go around this issue?

Answer (score 3):

The exception is fairly explicit - such case is not supported by default. You have to remember that `Datasets` are encoded into relational schema, so all required fields have to be declared up-front and bounded. There is no place here for recursive structure.

There is small window here - [binary `Encoders`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36648128/10465355):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Encoder, Encoders}

sparkSession.createDataset(List(
  BulletPoint("1", Nil), BulletPoint("2", Nil)
))(Encoders.kryo[BulletPoint])
```

or equivalent:

```
implicit val bulletPointEncoder = Encoders.kryo[BulletPoint]

sparkSession.createDataset(List(
  BulletPoint("1", Nil), BulletPoint("2", Nil)
))
```

but it is really not something you'd like to have in your code, unless strictly necessary.

Comment: This seems to me the only solution, i was trying to see if there was some other solution. Big thanks for the support.