# How to use Spark temp view with column as recursive case class

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Let's say I have a recursive case class (which means it reference itself):
`case class Dummy(id: Int, children: List[Dummy])`
I cannot use Spark default encoder with it, because the default encoder didn't support circular reference

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: cannot have circular references in class, but got the circular reference of class Dummy
```

So I need to use a custom encoder like kryo which supports recursive case class like below:

```
val myEncoder: Encoder[Dummy] = Encoders.kryo[Dummy]
val ds = spark.createDataset(Seq(Dummy(1, null)))(myEncoder)
ds.createOrReplaceTempView("myTable")
```

This works fine and I can operate one the Dataset well, but what I need is to write Spark SQL and operate the fields in case class like below:

```
%%sql
select id, size(children) as childCount from myTable
```

But I got this error:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`id`' given input columns: [myTable.value]; line 1 pos 7;
```

Because the schema is:

```
value: binary (nullable = true)
```

Note: the problem seems like [spark-using-recursive-case-class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54241088/spark-using-recursive-case-class) but not the same. I need a way to write SQL to operate on the case class instead of using dataset api.

I have already tried to use kryo solution, but it didn't work. Does Spark support deserialize case class automatically when writing SQL?

Comment: why you want circular reference, why not just create another case class.

Comment: This is a tree structure, so circular reference is necessary. Another approach is replace children: List[Dummy] to childIds: List[Int], then have another map to map id to element. But it will be hard to use.