# Apache Spark Scala with Play-json Validation

Tags: scala, apache-spark, play-json

java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type [trait object] is not supported

```
trait Container {
  def aa: String
  def bb: Int
}

case class First(aa: String, bb: Int) extends Container
case class Second(aa: String, bb: Int) extends Container

implicit val aaContainerFormat: Format[First] = Json.format[First]

implicit val bbContainerFormat: Format[Second] = Json.format[Second]

implicit def nodeContainerReads: Reads[Container] =
  try {
    Json.format[First].map(x => x: Container) or
    Json.format[Second].map(x => x: Container)
  } catch {
    case e: Exception => Reads {
      case _ => JsError(JsonValidationError("Cannot De-serialize value."))
    }
  }

implicit def nodeContainerWrites = new Writes[Container] {
  override def writes(node: Container): JsValue = node match {
    case a: First => Json.toJson(a)
    case b: Second => Json.toJson(b)
    case _ => Json.obj("error" -> "wrong Json")
  }
}

// Example Usage....
val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder.appName("Unit Test").getOrCreate()
val js: Container = First("unit", "test")

spark.createDataFrame(Seq(js))
```

I expect the output of Datasets of [Container Object] but the actual output is java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type Container is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

Spark does not use typeclasses from Play JSON to convert Scala types into Spark SQL types. Instead you need to look at [Spark Encoders](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-Encoder.html) which form the basis of conversions for Scala types to Spark types. If you have the Spark Session in scope, you can use `import sparkSession.implicits._` so it will automatically create encoders for your case classes. I believe that Spark doesn't support sum-types out of the box so you would need to implement your own Encoder to somehow model that in Spark in an ad-hoc fashion. Please read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36648128/how-to-store-custom-objects-in-dataset) for more information if you want to encode sum types in Spark

Comment: I tried `import sparkSession.implicits._`  but still the same error, I've tried implement custom Encoders but I still didn't find way yet.

Comment: So doing the implicits import will not help you if you want to represent a sum-type. You will need to take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36648128/how-to-store-custom-objects-in-dataset#answer-51957666 which goes into how you define a User Defined Type which is your use case