# How to convert RDD[(String, Iterable[VertexId])] to DataFrame?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, spark-graphx

I have created an `RDD` from `Graphx` which looks like this:

```
val graph = GraphLoader.edgeListFile(spark.sparkContext, fileName)
var s: VertexRDD[VertexId] = graph.connectedComponents().vertices

val nodeGraph: RDD[(String, Iterable[VertexId])] = s.groupBy(_._2) map { case (x, y) =>
  val rand = randomUUID().toString
  val clusterList: Iterable[VertexId] = y.map(_._1)
  (rand, clusterList)
}
```

`nodeGraph` is of type `RDD[(String, Iterable[VertexId])]`, and the data inside will be of the form:

```
(abc-def11, Iterable(1,2,3,4)), 
(def-aaa, Iterable(10,11)), 
...
```

What I want to do now is to create a dataframe out of it, that should look like this:

```
col1        col2
abc-def11   1
abc-def11   2
abc-def11   3
abc-def11   4
def-aaa     10
def-aaa     11
```

How to do this in Spark?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, convert the RDD to a dataframe using `toDF()`, with your wanted column names. This is easiest done by changing `Iterable[VertexId]` to `Seq[Long]` first.

```
import spark.implicits._
val df = nodeGraph.map(x => (x._1, x._2.map(_.toLong).toSeq)).toDF("col1", "col2")
```

Note that this could be done while creating `nodeGraph` to save a step. Next, use the `explode` function to flatten the dataframe,

```
val df2 = df.withColumn("col2", explode($"col2"))
```

which will give you the desired output.

Comment: I have one question, is `.toSeq` going to be a problem, what if Iterable has billion records, is it going to explode or fail if Iterable has billion records while calling ``toSeq` on it

Comment: @Aamir: Seq is an extension to Iterable but I don't think it would have any performance impact. The reason behind the conversion is that Spark do not supply any in-built encoder for conversion from Iterable. It's possible to add with kyro but not as straight-forward (see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36648128/how-to-store-custom-objects-in-dataset).