# Problem creating dataset in Spark and Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I ran into a problem using spark dataset!
I keep getting the exception about encoders when I want to use case class
the code is a simple one below:

```
case class OrderDataType (orderId: String, customerId: String, orderDate: String)
import spark.implicits._

val ds = spark.read.option("header", "true").csv("data\\orders.csv").as[OrderDataType]
```

I get this exception during compile:

> Unable to find encoder for type OrderDataType. An implicit Encoder[OrderDataType] is needed to store OrderDataType instances in a Dataset. Primitive types (Int, String, etc) and Product types (case classes) are supported by importing spark.implicits._  Support for serializing other types will be added in future releases.

I have already added this: **import spark.implicits._** but it doesn't solve the problem!

According to spark and scala documentation, the encoding must be done implicitly with scala!

What is wrong with this code and what should I do to fix it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define your case class **outside** of **`main`** method then in main  method read the csv file and convert to `dataset`.

**`Example:`**

```
case class OrderDataType (orderId: String, customerId: String, orderDate: String)
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
val ds = spark.read.option("header", "true").csv("data\\orders.csv").as[OrderDataType]
}

//or

def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val ds = spark.read.option("header", "true").csv("data\\orders.csv").as[(String,String,String)]
    }
```

Comment: thanks, why I couldn't use case class inside a method?

Comment: I faced this but not totally understand it here are the some useful links..  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36648128/how-to-store-custom-objects-in-dataset  https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-Encoder.html

Answer (score 1):

Other way is ... you can use every thing inside `object Orders extends App` (intelligent enough to identify case class from out side of def main)

mydata/Orders.csv

```
orderId,customerId,orderDate
1,2,21/08/1977
1,2,21/08/1978
```

Example code :

```
package examples

import org.apache.log4j.Level
import org.apache.spark.sql._

object Orders extends App {
  val logger = org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger("org")
  logger.setLevel(Level.WARN)


  val spark = SparkSession.builder.appName(getClass.getName)
    .master("local[*]").getOrCreate


  case class OrderDataType(orderId: String, customerId: String, orderDate: String)

  import spark.implicits._

  val ds1 = spark.read.option("header", "true").csv("mydata/Orders.csv").as[OrderDataType]
  ds1.show
}
```

Result :

```
+-------+----------+----------+
|orderId|customerId| orderDate|
+-------+----------+----------+
|      1|         2|21/08/1977|
|      1|         2|21/08/1978|
+-------+----------+----------+
```

Why case class outside of def main ....

[Seems like this is by design of the `Encoder` from annotation
`@implicitNotFound` below](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Encoder.scala#L65)