# Union generic type without Either Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, generics, union-types, apache-spark-encoders

This works fine:

```
def echo[A, B](a: A, b: B): A = ???
```

This is also fine:

```
def echo[A, B](a: A, b: B): B = ???
```

> However, how do we achieve this to return either type A or B?
>
> ```
> // error
> def echo[A, B](a: A, b: B): A|B = ???
> ```

Is it simply possible to have a **union type** of **generic** types **A** and **B**?
Cheers.

---

**UPDATE1**

`Either` is an option but not ideal, as it requires a **pattern match** when processing the returned result. Effectively, I want this: `A <: A|B`, `B <: A|B`, which `Either` does not achieve.

Another extreme, I can do this, but type is too loose:

```
def echo[A, B](a: A, b: B): Any = ???
```

---

**UPDATE2**
Why I don't want `Either`?

(Reason 2)

The returned result would actually be a `Dataset` of **Spark**, which requires `Encoder` for any type that is not a subtype of `Product` (see [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36648128/how-to-store-custom-objects-in-dataset)).

When calling this method many times, it ends up with too many `Either` wrapping each other, e.g. `Either[Either[Either[...]]]`. This requires too many encoders to be defined.

So I'm actually doing this:

```
def echo[A, B](a: A, b: B): Dataset[A|B] = ???
```

If I do this it would require to have many different encoders due to `Either` type:

```
def echo[A, B](a: A, b: B): Dataset[Either[A, B]] = ???
val result1: Either[Cat, Dog] = echo(a: Cat, b: Dog)
val result2: Either[Either[Cat, Dog], Pig] = echo(result1: Either[Cat, Dog], c: Pig)

// we have to define encoders:
implicit encoder1: org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders.kryo[Either[Cat, Dog]]
implicit encoder2: org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders.kryo[Either[Either[Cat, Dog], Pig]]

// if we keep iterating, then too many encoders to define...
```

Comment: well, there's [Either](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0/scala/util/Either.html)

Comment: Sounds like function specialization from C++ would have been handy here

Comment: @smac89 Thanks for that, good to know. But it seems `@specialized` only works for specific types, meaning it cannot do `def echo[@specialized(A,B) AB](a: A, b: B, ab: AB) = ???` (where `A` and `B` are generic types). Secondly, it seems it cannot return a `@specialized` type e.g. `def echo[A, B](a: A, b: B): @specialized(A,B) = ???` Both errors!

Comment: @Dima Thanks! `Either` is not bad, but it requires a pattern match when processing the returned result. Effectively, I want this: `A <: A|B`, `B <: A|B`, which `Either` does not achieve.

Comment: Union type also requires a pattern match.

Comment: @jack If you don't know the actual type of the returned value, you are going to have to match in the end to be able to do anything meaningful with it (other than trivial stuff like `print` or `equals`, but for that you could just use `Any`).

Comment: It seems you have a design problem in your **Spark** code since Scala 2 doesn't really support union types your current approach is doomed.

Answer (score 2):

Soon-to-be-released Scala 3 has it.

```
def echo[A, B](a: A, b: B): A|B = ???  //this compiles
```

As can be seen in [this Scastie session](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/G8NPAAuFSfSlOBowXChwtw).

Comment: Thanks for reaching out. In Scala 2.11, it still does not compile, is there way to achieve this?