# Datasets of Arrays in Spark (1.6.1)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

So I've been attempting to reformat a project I'm working on to use the Dataset API and have been having some issues with encoding errors. From what I've read, I think that I should be able to store Arrays of primitive values in a dataset. However, the following class gives me encoding errors:

```
case class InvertedIndex(partition:Int, docs:Array[Int], indices:Array[Long], weights:Array[Double])

val inv = RDD[InvertedIndex]
val invertedIndexDataset = sqlContext.createDataset(inv)
invertedIndexDataset.groupBy(x => x.partition).mapGroups {
    //...
}
```

Could someone please help me understand what the issue is here? Can Datasets not currently handle Arrays of primitives, or is there something extra that I need to do to make them work?

Thank you

edit 1:

Here is the full error I am getting

```
Error:(223, 84) Unable to find encoder for type stored in a Dataset.  Primitive types (Int, String, etc) and Product types (case classes) are supported by importing spark.implicits._  Support for serializing other types will be added in future releases.
    val similarities = invertedIndexDataset.groupByKey(x => x.partition).mapGroups {
```

Comment: You might want to have a look at [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36449368/using-an-optionsome-primitive-type-in-spark-dataset-api). What is the specific error you are getting ?

Comment: Do you have:   import sqlContext.implicits._

Comment: @RobertHorvick Yes, however I import it in the function so would that cause a problem? (this function takes in the sparkContext as a parameter so it would be hard to have a class-wide sqlContext)

Comment: @Hawknight I am getting the same error as that post, but my case class is defined outside of the function so I'm not sure why it's happening.

Comment: Please share the exact and complete error message you are getting.

Comment: @RobertHorvick I've included the full error message.

Answer (score 0):

The following works as expected in Spark 2.0.

```
import spark.implicits._

spark.createDataset( Array(1,2) :: Array(1) :: Array(2) :: Nil )
res0:org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[Array[Int]] = [value: array<int>]
```