# Type issues when using flatMapGroups

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-2.0, apache-spark-dataset

I am translating spark-1.6 rdd to spark-2.x datasets

The original code was:

```
val sample_data : Dataset[(Int, Array[Double])]
val samples : Array[Array[Array[Double]]] = sample_data.rdd
  .groupBy(x => x._1)
  .map(x => {
   val (id: Int, points: Iterable[(Int, Array[Double])]) = x
   val data1 = points.map(x => x._2).toArray
   data1
}).collect()
```

The `sample_data.rdd` no longer works so I am trying to do the same operations using datasets. The new approach uses flatMapGroups

```
val sample_data : Dataset[(Int, Array[Double])]
val samples : Array[Array[Array[Double]]] = sample_data
  .groupByKey(x => x._1)
  .flatMapGroups ( (id: Int, points: Iterable[(Int, Array[Double])]) =>
    Iterator(points.map((x:Int, y:Array[Double]) => y)).toList
  ).collect()
```

The error given is:

> Error:(36, 25) overloaded method value map with alternatives:   [B,
>   That](f: ((Int, Array[Double])) => B)(implicit bf:
>   scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[Iterable[(Int,
>   Array[Double])],B,That])That    [B](f: ((Int, Array[Double])) =>
>   B)Iterator[B]  cannot be applied to ((Int, Array[Double]) =>
>   Array[Double])
>           Iterator(points.map((x:Int, y:Array[Double])
>    => y)).toList

Can you please provide an example of how to use flatMapGroups and how to understand the given error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`points` is actually an `Iterator`, but you are casting it to an `Iterable`, so the compiler is telling you to make it an `Iterator`.

This is what you are trying to do:

```
val samples: Array[Array[Array[Double]]] = sample_data
    .groupByKey(_._1)
    .flatMapGroups((id: Int, points: Iterator[(Int, Array[Double])]) =>
        Iterator(points.map(_._2).toArray)
    ).collect()
```

Rewrapping in an Iterator isn't serving you a purpose, so you can just use mapGroups like so:

```
.mapGroups((_, points) => points.map(_._2).toArray)
```

However in both cases, there is no encoder for an Array[Array[_]]. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36449368/how-to-create-encoder-for-option-type-constructor-e-g-optionint) for more detail.

So either implement the implicit Encoder yourself ([existing Encoders](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.1.0/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/SQLImplicits.scala#L40-L126)), or stick to the `RDD` interface.

Comment: The implicit Encoder for this example is: 
    `implicit def arrayOfArray: org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder[Array[Array[Double]]] = org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder()`